# Get a pixel from HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to query a HTML Canvas object to get the color at a specific location?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

There's a section about [pixel manipulation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#pixel-manipulation) in the W3C documentation.

Here's [an example on how to invert an image](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/#pixelbasedmanipulation):

```
var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

// Get the CanvasPixelArray from the given coordinates and dimensions.
var imgd = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
var pix = imgd.data;

// Loop over each pixel and invert the color.
for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    pix[i  ] = 255 - pix[i  ]; // red
    pix[i+1] = 255 - pix[i+1]; // green
    pix[i+2] = 255 - pix[i+2]; // blue
    // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)
}

// Draw the ImageData at the given (x,y) coordinates.
context.putImageData(imgd, x, y);
```

Comment: Pixel manipulation section is now available here : https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext2/#pixel-manipulation

Answer (score 66):

Try the [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context) method:

```
var data = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
var rgb = [ data[0], data[1], data[2] ];
```

Comment: shouldn't this be context.getImageData() and not canvas.getImageData()?

Comment: @Crashalot depends on what the var "canvas" contains, it could simply be the context of a canvas with a crappy var name.

Comment: Wow, very elegant! I thought about searching for the point in the entire context, but this is much smarter.

Comment: This is clever, but if you're going to be calling getPixel a lot, it is *much* faster to cache the ImageData object for the whole image (0,0,width,height), and then compute the index using `idx = (y * width + x) * 4` like Georg's answer. However, don't forget to refresh that cached object every time the image changes.

Comment: That's true @Noio, however my answer is specific to the question above (i.e. the color of a pixel).

Comment: What's that `Color()` constructor? That doesn't seem to exist anywhere

Comment: This is very slow if you need to get every pixel in the image

Comment: @SalientBrain indeed, but it's convenient if you only need the color at specific location (which was the question)

Comment: @Theo.T just wanted to point it out. Qwerty's approach is fast and convenient

Answer (score 16):

Yes sure, provided you have its context. *(See how to get canvas context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705693/985454).)*

```
var imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
// { data: [r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,..], ... }

function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data
  return [d[i],d[i+1],d[i+2],d[i+3]] // Returns array [R,G,B,A]
}

// AND/OR

function getPixelXY(imgData, x, y) {
  return getPixel(imgData, y*imgData.width+x)
}
```

---

**PS:** If you plan to mutate the data and draw them back on the canvas, you can use `subarray`

```
var
  idt = imgData, // See previous code snippet
  a = getPixel(idt, 188411), // Array(4) [0, 251, 0, 255]
  b = idt.data.subarray(188411*4, 188411*4 + 4) // Uint8ClampedArray(4) [0, 251, 0, 255]

a[0] = 255 // Does nothing
getPixel(idt, 188411) // Array(4) [0, 251, 0, 255]

b[0] = 255 // Mutates the original imgData.data
getPixel(idt, 188411) // Array(4) [255, 251, 0, 255]

// Or use it in the function
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data
  return imgData.data.subarray(i, i+4) // Returns subarray [R,G,B,A]
}
```

You can experiment with this on http://qry.me/xyscope/, the code for this is in the source, just copy/paste it in the console.

Comment: Yay! Thanks it works very well and it is waay faster than calling `context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);`

Comment: It is faster indeed. Thanks!

Comment: That's ok if there is no credits for my (very) small contribution, but thanks for willing to. ^^ Your answer is already a pro move and deserved another upvote by who you know, so my joy is complete. :-)

Comment: Just as a side note, your answer helped me to find a way to write a flood fill of a closed area. Even if my code is still not good (really a _stack overflow_, too much recursion for a given amount of pixel to fill) your answer is a cobblestone of the way leading to my goal. So big thanks!

Comment: @Amessihel Nice, thanks for the heads-up and praise . Anyway, sometimes it is better to use `while` with a storage to avoid stack overflow with too much recursion.

Comment: @Qwerty, the algo I wrote is quite naive, it checks the current pixel color and fill it if it matches the color of the first hit pixel, then performs a call for each pixel in the immediate neighborhood (N,E,S,W). The recursion is deep and not trivial to convert to an iteration "as is".

Comment: @Amessihel I would love to see it, would you mind posting that to a gist?

Comment: @Qwerty, basically it is the same approach than the first sample of this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56221940.

Comment: @Amessihel I hoped you create a gist so that I can comment better, but there is everything written already on that answer.. How to write it using a stack and even in a worker, wow!

Comment: @Qwerty yes, I noticed that. I remember also the behavior of command `FILL` provided with the Locomotive Basic of the Amstrad CPC which floods fill same-colour area, My goal is to get an iterative algorithm if possible. :)

Comment: @Qwerty (Here is a gist: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2099423.)

Answer (score 10):

```
function GetPixel(context, x, y)
{
    var p = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; 
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);  
    return hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: ctx should be set as a attribute in GetPixel though

Comment: Nice rgbToHex return statement

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 8):

Yup, check out [`getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context). Here's an example of breaking CAPTCHA with JavaScript using canvas:

*[OCR and Neural Nets in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/)*

Answer (score 7):

Note that `getImageData` returns a snapshot. Implications are:

- Changes will not take effect until subsequent `putImageData`
- `getImageData` and `putImageData` calls are relatively slow

Answer (score 5):

```js
//Get pixel data
var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);

//Color at (x,y) position
var color = [];
color['red'] = imageData.data[((y*(imageData.width*4)) + (x*4)) + 0];
color['green'] = imageData.data[((y*(imageData.width*4)) + (x*4)) + 1];
color['blue'] = imageData.data[((y*(imageData.width*4)) + (x*4)) + 2];
color['alpha'] = imageData.data[((y*(imageData.width*4)) + (x*4)) + 3];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `i << 2`.

```
const data = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height).data;
const pixels = [];

for (let i = 0, dx = 0; dx < data.length; i++, dx = i << 2) {
    pixels.push({
        r: data[dx  ],
        g: data[dx+1],
        b: data[dx+2],
        a: data[dx+3]
    });
}
```

Comment: More explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

## Fast and handy

Use following class which implement fast method described in [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/) and contains all you need: `readPixel`, `putPixel`, get `width/height`. Class update canvas after calling `refresh()` method. Example solve simple case of 2d [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation)

```js
class Screen{
  constructor(canvasSelector) {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector(canvasSelector);
    this.width  = this.canvas.width;
    this.height = this.canvas.height;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.imageData = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.buf = new ArrayBuffer(this.imageData.data.length);
    this.buf8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(this.buf);
    this.data = new Uint32Array(this.buf);  
  }
  
  // r,g,b,a - red, gren, blue, alpha components in range 0-255
  putPixel(x,y,r,g,b,a=255) {
    this.data[y * this.width + x] = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (g <<  8) | r;
  }
  
  readPixel(x,y) {
    let p= this.data[y * this.width + x]
    return [p&0xff, p>>8&0xff, p>>16&0xff, p>>>24];
  }

  refresh() {
    this.imageData.data.set(this.buf8);
    this.ctx.putImageData(this.imageData, 0, 0);
  }
}




// --------
// TEST
// --------

let s=new Screen('#canvas');

function draw() {

  for (var y = 1; y < s.height-1; ++y) {
    for (var x = 1; x < s.width-1; ++x) {      
      let a = [[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]].reduce((a,[xp,yp])=> 
        a+= s.readPixel(x+xp,y+yp)[0]
      ,0);
      let v=a/2-tmp[x][y];
      tmp[x][y]=v<0 ? 0:v;
    }
  }

  for (var y = 1; y < s.height-1; ++y) {
    for (var x = 1; x < s.width-1; ++x) {  
      let v=tmp[x][y];
      tmp[x][y]= s.readPixel(x,y)[0];
      s.putPixel(x,y, v,v,v);
    }
  }

  s.refresh();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

// temporary 2d buffer ()for solving wave equation)
let tmp = [...Array(s.width)].map(x => Array(s.height).fill(0));

function move(e) { s.putPixel(e.x-10, e.y-10, 255,255,255);}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="150" width="512" onmousemove="move(event)"></canvas>
<div>Move mouse on black box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract a particular color of pixel by passing the coordinates of pixel into the function, this will come in handy:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function detectColor(x, y){
  data=ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  col={
    r:data[0],
    g:data[1],
    b:data[2]
  };
  return col;
}
```

`x`, `y` is the coordinate you want to filter out color.

```
var color = detectColor(x, y)
```

The color is the object, you will get the RGB value by `color.r`, `color.g`, `color.b`.