# How can I use JavaScript or jQuery to read a pixel of an image when user clicks it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use JavaScript or jQuery to read the color of a pixel of an image when the user clicks on it? (of course we have the (x,y) value of this pixel by subscribing to the click event).

Comment: Are you trying to make a color picker?

Comment: Not really, try to programmatically access an image imbedded in a page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159044/getting-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-an-image-with-jquery

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you can draw the image in a canvas element then you can use the [`getImageData`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#pixel-manipulation) method to return an array containing RGBA values.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image.jpg';
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
data = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
```

Answer (score 8):

This solution will be **much faster** if you need to read the pixels repeatedly.

## The magic ®

```
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data
  return [d[i],d[i+1],d[i+2],d[i+3]] // [R,G,B,A]
}

function getPixelXY(imgData, x, y) {
  return getPixel(imgData, y*imgData.width+x)
}
```

## Where do you get imgData?

1. create `<canvas>`
2. get canvas `context`
3. copy `<img>` to `<canvas>`
4. get canvas image data (an array of values `[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,..]`)
5. **do `The magic`®**

### le code:

```
var cvs = document.createElement('canvas'),
    img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]   // your image goes here
    // img = $('#yourImage')[0]                     // can use jquery for selection
cvs.width = img.width; cvs.height = img.height
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d")
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height)
var idt = ctx.getImageData(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height)

// The magic®
getPixel(idt, 852)  // returns array [red, green, blue, alpha]
getPixelXY(idt,1,1) // same pixel using x,y
```

For a working example see source code of http://qry.me/xyscope/

---

**PS:** If you plan to mutate the data and draw them back on the canvas, you can use `subarray`

```
var
 a = getPixel(idt, 188411), // Array(4) [0, 251, 0, 255]
 b = idt.data.subarray(188411*4, 188411*4 + 4) // Uint8ClampedArray(4) [0, 251, 0, 255]

a[0] = 255 // does nothing
getPixel(idt, 188411) // Array(4) [0, 251, 0, 255]

b[0] = 255 // mutates the original imgData.data
getPixel(idt, 188411) // Array(4) [255, 251, 0, 255]

// or use it in the function
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data
  return imgData.data.subarray(i, i+4) // returns subarray [R,G,B,A]
}
```

You can experiment with this on http://qry.me/xyscope/, the code for this is in the source, just copy/paste it in the console.