# getting the X/Y coordinates of a mouse click on an image with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to use jQuery to get the X/Y coordinates of a click event on an image. The coordinates should be relative to the image, not relative to the whole page

Comment: These 3 links provide good answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/4249711/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/3236129/  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10429969/

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can use [`pageX` and `pageY`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/event.shtml) to get the position of the mouse in the window. You can also use jQuery's [`offset`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) to get the position of an element.

So, it should be `pageX - offset.left` for how far from the left of the image and `pageY - offset.top` for how far from the top of the image.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    alert(e.pageX - offset.left);
    alert(e.pageY - offset.top);
  });
});
```

I've made a [live example here](http://jsbin.com/akiwo) and [here](http://jsbin.com/akiwo/edit) is the source.

To calculate how far from the bottom or right, you would have to use jQuery's [`width`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/width) and [`height`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height) methods.

Comment: @Brian : Thanks so much for your solution!!! This resolves my problem when webpage zooms in/out.

Comment: still doesn't work hen you scroll the page it spits different results

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, but took me a while to put into words what I was looking for.

Comment: As @beerwin mentioned, this doesn't work when scrolling the page. If you need the coordinates based on the page rather than the viewable window, use `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` instead.

Comment: Exactly! In most cases e.pageX and e.pageY is what you want.

Comment: Sorry @BrianMcKenna, I don't want to get the position, I want direct click in the position of the <canvas> tag. How to do this?

Comment: @vanloc did you find solution on your <canvas> click?

Answer (score 26):

note! there is a difference between `e.clientX` & `e.clientY` and `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`

try them both out and make sure you are using the proper one. `clientX` and `clientY` change based on scrolling position

Answer (score 20):

Here is a better script:

```
$('#mainimage').click(function(e)
{   
    var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

    var left = Math.round( (e.clientX - offset_l) );
    var top = Math.round( (e.clientY - offset_t) );

    alert("Left: " + left + " Top: " + top);

});
```

Comment: For sure better than the selected one.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this better? Anyone has some constructive reasoning for this?

Answer (score 9):

The below code works always even if any image makes the window scroll.

```
$(function() {
    $("#demo-box").click(function(e) {

      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
      var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

      alert("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);

    });
});
```

Ref: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-x-y-mouse-coordinates/

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/ZZEk8/ for a working example of the below:

```
<img id='myImg' src='/my/img/link.gif' />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('click', function () {
        // Add a click-handler to the image.
        $('#myImg').bind('click', function (ev) {
            var $img = $(ev.target);

            var offset = $img.offset();
            var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
            var y = ev.clientY - offset.top;

            alert('clicked at x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that the above will get you the x and the y relative to the image's box - but will not correctly take into account margin, border and padding. These elements aren't actually part of the image, in your case - but they might be part of the element that you would want to take into account.

In this case, you should also use `$div.outerWidth(true) - $div.width()` and `$div.outerHeight(true) - $div.height()` to calculate the amount of margin / border / etc.

Your new code might look more like:

```
<img id='myImg' src='/my/img/link.gif' />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('click', function () {
        // Add a click-handler to the image.
        $('#myImg').bind('click', function (ev) {
            var $img = $(ev.target);

            var offset = $img.offset(); // Offset from the corner of the page.
            var xMargin = ($img.outerWidth() - $img.width()) / 2;
            var yMargin = ($img.outerHeight() - $img.height()) / 2;
            // Note that the above calculations assume your left margin is 
            // equal to your right margin, top to bottom, etc. and the same 
            // for borders.

            var x = (ev.clientX + xMargin) - offset.left;
            var y = (ev.clientY + yMargin) - offset.top;

            alert('clicked at x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My solution, also, needs to be updated to reflect pageX and pageY - just noted the above comments. This will not work correctly when scrolling - but there is already an accepted answer. :)