# Using jQuery how to get click coordinates on the target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following event handler for my html element

```
jQuery("#seek-bar").click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    alert(x);    
});
```

I need to find the position of the mouse on the #seek-bar at the time of clicking. I would have thought the above code should work, but it gives incorrect result

Comment: Position relative to the element, the viewport or the entire document?

Comment: I made it work using e.layerX - e.target.offsetLeft and for Oprea just used e.offsetX

Comment: if you wish to get it on a responsive site. try this article, you can get it on responsive sites as well. http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/03/get-exact-top-left-position-mouse-pointer-location-using-jquery/

Comment: e.offsetX seems to work on Firefox and Chrome as well.  According to [jQuery page](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) it is copied but not *normalized*.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Are you trying to get the  position of mouse pointer `relative` to element ( or ) simply the mouse pointer location
Try this Demo : [**http://jsfiddle.net/AMsK9/**](http://jsfiddle.net/AMsK9/)

---

### Edit :

1) `event.pageX`, `event.pageY` gives you the mouse position relative document !

**Ref** : http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/
       http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/

2) `offset()` : It gives the offset position of an element

**Ref** :  http://api.jquery.com/offset/

3) `position()` : It gives you the relative Position of an element i.e.,

consider an element is embedded inside another element

**example** :

```
<div id="imParent">
   <div id="imchild" />
</div>
```

**Ref** : http://api.jquery.com/position/

***HTML***

```
<body>
   <div id="A" style="left:100px;"> Default    <br /> mouse<br/>position </div>
   <div id="B" style="left:300px;"> offset()   <br /> mouse<br/>position </div>
   <div id="C" style="left:500px;"> position() <br /> mouse<br/>position </div>
</body>
```

***JavaScript***

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $('#A').click(function (e) { //Default mouse Position 
        alert(e.pageX + ' , ' + e.pageY);
    });

    $('#B').click(function (e) { //Offset mouse Position
        var posX = $(this).offset().left,
            posY = $(this).offset().top;
        alert((e.pageX - posX) + ' , ' + (e.pageY - posY));
    });

    $('#C').click(function (e) { //Relative ( to its parent) mouse position 
        var posX = $(this).position().left,
            posY = $(this).position().top;
        alert((e.pageX - posX) + ' , ' + (e.pageY - posY));
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the examples...one note though I'd also add the code here, if your link dies this question becomes useless in the future, I'd put the code for each and a brief description here :)

Comment: There is a simpler way to do the case of `'#B'`: `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY`. I guess you'd like to edit it. I already updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AMsK9/101/). I found this solution thanks to the post, so thanks.

Comment: Thanks, because I personally confused with offset() and position(), for anyone need further clarification may read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset for convenience sake

Comment: I had an element fixed to the bottom - that was 100% width, so I used window width as the posX instead - So I was able to determine if a user was cliking an "X" that was made with a :after css rule that was in the top right corner.

Comment: Great example, but there is not obvious what is the difference between .position() and .offset(). You should wrap element #C in some parent div with some exemplary position to see that the click on #C returns your mouse position inside the element that is parent of #C, which is probably least frequently useful.

Comment: For future readers: Here is a better demo of Avinash' Explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/AMsK9/558/

Comment: This gets messed up with element margin

Answer (score 19):

```
$('#something').click(function (e){
    var elm = $(this);
    var xPos = e.pageX - elm.offset().left;
    var yPos = e.pageY - elm.offset().top;

    console.log(xPos, yPos);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $("#special").click(function(e){
      $('#status2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

Here you can find more [**info**](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) with DEMO

Answer (score 1):

**In percentage :**

```
$('.your-class').click(function (e){
    var $this = $(this); // or use $(e.target) in some cases;
    var offset = $this.offset();
    var width = $this.width();
    var height = $this.height();
    var posX = offset.left;
    var posY = offset.top;
    var x = e.pageX-posX;
        x = parseInt(x/width*100,10);
        x = x<0?0:x;
        x = x>100?100:x;
    var y = e.pageY-posY;
        y = parseInt(y/height*100,10);
        y = y<0?0:y;
        y = y>100?100:y;
    console.log(x+'% '+y+'%');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If [MouseEvent.offsetX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX#Browser_compatibility) by your browser (all major browsers actually support it),  The jQuery [Event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) will contain this property.

> The MouseEvent.offsetX read-only property provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.

```
$("#seek-bar").click(function(event) {
  var x = event.offsetX
  alert(x);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see here [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/thamtucity/pen/QadLjw)

**html**

```
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div id="myPosition">
</div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
#myPosition{
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myPosition").click(function(e){
       var elm = $(this);
       var xPos = e.pageX - elm.offset().left;
       var yPos = e.pageY - elm.offset().top;
       alert("X position: " + xPos + ", Y position: " + yPos);
    });
});
```