# How to add event listeners to pseudo elements (like :after or :before) in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add `onClick` event listeners to pseudo elements (like `:after` or `:before`) in **ReactJS** without using native Javascript functions.?

Comment: There are no native javascript functions to add event listeners to `:before` or `:after`, you can hack through using clicked position, but that would be same in ReactJS

Comment: No, in plain javascript you can't too. Explain:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301510/5062956

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, even with Native JavaScript functions.

Pseudo-elements, as the name suggests, aren't *real* elements. They do not actually  exist in the [DOM (Document Object Model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

And since they are not part of the DOM, they do not have a [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), which could be referenced.

The only way you could possibly do that is if you know the exact position of the pseudo element. Then you can trigger a function on every click, which compares the coordinates of the cursor and the pseudo element.