# Use javascript to click on a pseudo-element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I'm wondering how to enable the clicking on a `:before` pseudo-element (the orange part of the div on the JSfiddle I link to below). I've read that since pseudo-elements aren't in the DOM you would need a hack for this. Unfortunately, I can't find an existing Stackoverflow Q&A that actually shows working code.

Link:  http://jsfiddle.net/Vv6Eb/4/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div { position:relative; background-color:#333;
      padding:20px; margin:20px; float:left; 
}

div:before { content:""; display:block; 
    padding:5px; background-color:#f60; border:2px solid white; 
    position: absolute; top:-2px; right:-2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include more information on what you want to happen?  It's possible there is some other workaround to achieve the intended result.

Comment: You can't bind directly to a pseudo-element, but you can bind to the element that's creating it and clicking the pseudo-element will always trigger the event that's bound to the generating element. If you specifically must only bind to the orange part, you need to create a new element.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, all i'm interested in is being able to click on the pseudo-element like one would click on a `<a>` or `<button>`. ComputerArts suggestion works for me though is there something else you're thinking?

Comment: @timpeterson I think I may have misunderstood your intent.  The question sounded as though you were trying to trigger a click on the element in javascript.  I was wondering what purpose that served.  Now I see that you were in fact looking to attack a click handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only detect click event on pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A workaround for this would be to dynamically append a `<span>` to the item and assigning a click method to it. [Like this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx22x/)

```
var item = $('<span />');
item.click(function() { alert('click'); });
$('div').append(item);
```

CSS

```
div { position:relative; background-color:#333;
      padding:20px; margin:20px; float:left;
}

div span { content:""; display:block;
    padding:5px; background-color:#f60; border:2px solid white;
    position: absolute; top:-2px; right:-2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you know where the circle "should" be, you can use trigonometry to see if the click is within the circle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vv6Eb/19/

```
$("div").click(function(e){
    var $me = $(this),
        width = $me.outerWidth(),
        height = $me.outerHeight(),
        top = $me.position().top,
        left = $me.position().left;

    var len = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width - e.offsetX, 2) + Math.pow(e.offsetY, 2));

    if (len < 10)
        alert('ding');
});​
```

Comment: don't use pow to calculate square, use `*`

Answer (score 2):

I know you are trying to use :before, but for this situation, can't you just create a new div with a class to use as a hook and append it to the original div?

Something like this might work:

```
var newDiv = $("<div class='orangeCircle'>");
$(".parentDivToOrangeCircle").append(newDiv);
```

And the CSS:

```
.parentDivToOrangeCircle { position:relative; background-color:#333;
    padding:20px; margin:20px; float:left; 
}

.orangeCircle {
    padding:5px; background-color:#f60; border:2px solid white; 
    position: absolute; top:-2px; right:-2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: -@Jordan, i don't need to use :before. If there is any another way I'd greatly appreciate to see what the code would look like.

Answer (score 1):

Do simply like using jquery

```js
  $(document).on("click", "span", function(e){
         if (e.offsetX > $(this)[0].offsetWidth) {
               alert('clicked on after');
    } 
    else
    {
    alert('clicked on main span');
    }
        
    })
```

```css
div { margin: 20px; }
span:after { content: 'AFTER'; position: absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>ELEMENT</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My purpose was solved by another workaround which is just adding a child DIV. Wrapping up all child elements inside the parent into this new child DIV:

My working sample as same as the problem statement: [See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamun_reza/jLf9m7xz/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    :before
    <div class="childDiv">
        <!-- child elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note: Ignore the `:before` in the HTML, just showing to understand.

**CSS:**

```
div.parentDiv{position:relative; background-color:#333; padding:0; margin:20px; float:left; }
div.parentDiv:before { content:""; display:block; padding:5px; background-color:#f60; border:2px solid white; position: absolute; top:-2px; right:-2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; cursor:pointer}

div.childDiv{padding:20px; margin:0}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('div.parentDiv').click(function(e){
        if( $(e.target).closest('.childDiv').length==0 ){
            //so clicked on psudo :before element!
            //do your work here ;)
            alert('Psudo :before element is clicked!');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [an article](https://medium.com/p/862deca19cca) about this on Medium.

Also, [the CodePen](https://codepen.io/theRealProHacker/embed/zYyEXaG?default-tab=html%2Cresult&editable=true)

The basic idea is tracing where the pseudo-element will be.
The code snippet below shows the more general case of a rectangle without a border-radius and closes the parent when the pseudo-element is clicked.

```js
const dismissable = document.querySelectorAll(".dismissable")

dismissable.forEach((d) => {
  d.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    // First we get the pseudo-elements style
    const target = e.currentTarget || e.target
    const after = getComputedStyle(target, ":after")
    if (after) {
      // Then we parse out the dimensions
      const atop = Number(after.getPropertyValue("top").slice(0, -2))
      const aheight = Number(after.getPropertyValue("height").slice(0, -2))
      const aleft = Number(after.getPropertyValue("left").slice(0, -2))
      const awidth = Number(after.getPropertyValue("width").slice(0, -2))
      // And get the mouse position
      const ex = e.layerX
      const ey = e.layerY
      // Finally we do a bounds check (Is the mouse inside of the after element)
      if (ex > aleft && ex < aleft+awidth && ey > atop && ey < atop+aheight) {
        console.log("Button clicked")
        target.style.display = "none"
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.dismissable {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dismissable:hover::after {
  content: "x";
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="dismissable"></div>
```