# How do I select an ::after selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please see the image below, I'm trying to select this to open the tab.[image]

HTML is  -

```
<div class="module collapsed" data-behavior="Quiver.Collapsable" data-collapse-trigger=".module-header">
    <div class="module-header">
      <h3>Admin Activity Log</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="module-content">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
        <% @admin_activity_messages.each do |message| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= message %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS is

```
&.collapsed {
    .module-header:after {
      content: '▼';
    }

    .module-content {
      display: none;
    }

    .module-actions {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Also, I don't think this is duplicated, I need to click this to run a test in order to 'open' this div

Comment: As a last comment - This is not a duplicated post. I want to click this element.

Comment: If so the question should be rephrased. However It *is* still a duplicate of these topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element ♦ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395858/event-listener-on-a-css-pseudo-element-such-as-before-or-after ♦ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692762/use-javascript-to-click-on-a-pseudo-element

Comment: Apart from that you have shown us only HTML (so we can’t see how `::after` does even come into play here) – you can not react on a click _specifically_ on such a pseudo element, you can only react to clicks on the element that `::after` is applied to itself.

Comment: I added the :after code. I was searching code base for ::after. Sorry for that...

Comment: @HashemQolami I can't distill those 3 separate posts into any solution for my problem.  Can you please remove the duplicate tag OR point me to a more specific duplication...

Comment: The first and second link explain why it is not possible to bind any event to pseudo-elements and the third link provides a workaround for that: Rather than using pseudo-elements, append an element — which has an `onclick` event attached — to the container dynamically.