# Is it possible to detect a click of an :after or :before pseudo element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Lets say I have:

```
<div></div>
```

with:

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Can I do something like `$('div:after').click(function(){...});` ? And have it not fire if I am clicking on `div` but not `div:after`.

Comment: Why don't you just split it into another element and save the headache?

Comment: Nope. That's why they are pseudo-elements.

Comment: @mattytommo I just want to know if its possible.

Comment: @watson The answer (as far as I'm aware) is no, unfortunately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe. Depending on how you structure your pseudo content you would have to rely on calculating mouse position for clicks on the actual div. The event handlers would all go on the div, and not the pseudo element because it doesn't exist in the DOM.

See [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)
 for some more info. Especially BoltClock's answer.

Also see Felix's comment for another possible solution without mouse position: [Only detect click event on pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element)

Comment: I can't find any comment from felix.