# Is it safe to use :after-selector with jquery=

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger a function when clicking a :after

For example

```
.foo:after{
    content: "read more";
}


$('foo:after').click(myFunction);
```

Will this cause any fuzz?

Comment: :after is a CSS pseudo class, there is no DOM element targeted by this selector

Comment: It will do nothing at all.

Comment: What I don't get is why you didn't try before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect or trigger events on [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) as they are not part of the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM).

Also see [Only detect click event on pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, :after is a pseudoselector which isn't part of the dom.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('foo:after')
```

Sorry, but this won't work. The `:after` pseudo-element is not available to your Javascript code.