# jQuery - Handle event on :before or :after content element

Tags: jquery, css, events

```
div:before {
    content: "\40ec";
}
```

A character appears inside the div.

Requirement - I require to handle click event only on this character in jQuery. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Comment: Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element