# How to find nearest child to a click location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/1bgun0k0/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/1bgun0k0/1/_)*

I have a DIV with several child SPANs.

```
<div id="parent">
    <span class="child">Alpha</span>
    <span class="child">Beta</span>
    <span class="child">Gamma</span>
</div>
```

Child elements have a margin:

```
#parent { padding: 5px; }    
.child { margin: 5px; }
```

When user clicks between child elements (or at either end of the parent DIV outside a child element), I need to insert a new child there.

How do I detect between which child elements user clicked?

---

Update: I need to support multiple rows of children (thanks, Roko, for the heads-up). Clicks between rows should be ignored. Clicks on the left and right side of the whole row should be handled correctly.

Comment: Define *between* cause on multiple rows you'll have i.e: 3 or 4 near-siblings.

Comment: Only left/right side of a child counts, clicks between rows should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click:

1. Iterate through each `child`, grabbing children on the left and right based on position in relation to the cursor.  (Check event.pageY to make sure they're on the right row.)
2. If a child to the left is found, keep iterating to the end.  The last left child will be the true left child.
3. If a child to the right is found, stop iterating.  This is the one you want.
4. If a left child is found, insert the text *and* a space *after* it.  You're done.
5. If a right child is found, insert the text *and* a space *before* it.

**Snippet**

```js
var n = 0;
$('#parent').click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.id === 'parent') {
    var parent= $(this),
        firstChild= $(this).find('.child').first(),
        lastChild = $(this).find('.child').last(),
        leftChild,
        rightChild,
        text= function() {return $('<span class="child new">New child '+(++n)+'</span>');}

    parent.find('.child').each(function() {
      var pos= $(this).offset(),
          h= $(this).height();
        
      if(pos.top <= e.pageY && pos.top+h >= e.pageY) {
        if(pos.left <= e.pageX) {
          leftChild= $(this);
        }
        else if(pos.left >= e.pageX) {
          rightChild= $(this);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
      
    if(leftChild) {
      leftChild.after(text()).after(' ');
    }
    else if(rightChild) {
      rightChild.before(text()).before(' ');
    }
    else if(!firstChild.length || e.pageY < firstChild.offset().top) {
      parent.prepend(text()).before(' ');
    }
    else if(e.pageY > lastChild.offset().top) {
      lastChild.after(text()).after(' ');
    }
    //otherwise, we're between rows
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#parent {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 450px;
  line-height: 2.7em;
}

.child {
  margin: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.new {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span class="child">Alpha</span>
  <span class="child">Beta</span>
  <span class="child">Gamma</span>
  <span class="child">Delta</span>
  <span class="child">Epsilon</span>
  <span class="child">Zeta</span>
  <span class="child">Eta</span>
  <span class="child">Theta</span>
  <span class="child">Iota</span>
  <span class="child">Kappa</span>
  <span class="child">Lambda</span>
  <span class="child">Mu</span>
  <span class="child">Nu</span>
  <span class="child">Xi</span>
  <span class="child">Omicron</span>
  <span class="child">Pi</span>
  <span class="child">Rho</span>
  <span class="child">Sigma</span>
  <span class="child">Tau</span>
  <span class="child">Upsilon</span>
  <span class="child">Phi</span>
  <span class="child">Chi</span>
  <span class="child">Psi</span>
  <span class="child">Omega</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Originally posted a much more complicated solution.  Don't know if I can improve on this.

Comment: Wow, much better! :) Don't forget `else {
      parent.append(text());
    }` for completeness...

Comment: If there's no left or right child, you are either between rows (which you said should be ignored), *or* you're in the top or bottom padding of the parent, which I assume should *not* be ignored.  So it may need a prepend or an append.  I'll update when I get the chance.

Comment: Now updated.  jsFiddle seems to be broken, so I've posted a Snippet instead.

Comment: The parent itself may be empty ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Since margins don't receive click events, I might suggest using a 5px placeholder div instead of a margin, so that clicking between children will result in a click to the placeholder.

On that click, you insert a new child (and a new 5px placeholder) underneath.

UPDATE: Since you changed the question from clicking between to clicking *beside*, you might try this trick using pseudo elements (to prevent divitis)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23243996/1998238

Comment: @Terry I agree that putting too many divs can make a page confusing, but this is probably for dynamically generated content, so I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use CSS to mask the area you are clicking. You can do this by wrapping your elements like so:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="alpha" class="spacer">
        <span class="child">Alpha</span>
    </div>
    <div id="beta" class="spacer">
        <span class="child">Beta</span>
    </div>
    <div id="gamma" class="spacer">
        <span class="child">Gamma</span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/theodin/5enfs52t/2/

Comment: SPAN is better wrapped with SPAN

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tukqnujm/2

This was suggested previously, but you can add transparent clickable elements between the others to act as margins.

```
var parent = $("#parent");
parent.on("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains("between")) {
        var item = document.createElement("span");
        item.classList.add("item");
        var between = document.createElement("span");
        between.classList.add("between");
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(item, e.target);
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(between, item);
    }
});
```

Be careful though, inline-block tags add a space to the document if there are spaces between elements, and those spaces won't be clickable. That's why I put comments in the jsfiddle.

```
   <div id="parent"><!--
    --><span class="between"></span><!--
    --><span class="item"></span><!--
    --><span class="between"></span><!--
--></div>
```

Comment: if you use `e.target.parentNode.insertBefore` than use also native elements selectors and `addEventListener`. Also, than, `ev.target` should be `ev.srcElement` for IE

Comment: Also, there are better techniques than hardcoding `<!---->` to remove inline space gaps

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah, my bad. I actually don't do much jQuery, so I don't know the jQuery equivalent of parentNode and insertBefore. The fiddle is in pure JS. As for the comment hardcode, I know. I usually put a loop which removes all blank textnodes from the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the position of the cursor (because the cursor will not be immediately over any `.child` element, so binding the click event to it is useless), and then retrieve a list of `.child` elements that are to the left of this coordinate. Get the last `.child` element that satisfy this criterea, append new element behind it.

Also, you should use `.on()` for the click event binding for `.child`, because newly added elements will not have the click event registered (because with your existing code, you are binding the click event at runtime, where newly added elements are not present on the page).

```
$('.child').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(".debug").removeClass("debug");
    $(this).toggleClass("debug");
})

$("#parent").click(function(e) { 
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(".debug").removeClass("debug");
    $(this).toggleClass("debug");

    // Get mouse position along x-axis
    var xPos = e.pageX,
        yPos = e.pageY;

    // Get x-axis offset of child
    // Return array of child elements that is to the left of mouseclick
    // and get the last child, append new element after it
    var $prevChild = $('.child').filter(function() {
        return ($(this).offset().left < xPos && $(this).offset().top < yPos)
    }),
        $content = $('<span class="child">New child</span>');

    // Additional logic from @AlexanderGladysh
    if ($prevChild.length > 0) {
        $content.insertAfter($prevChild.last());
    } else {
        $(this).prepend($content);
    }
})
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/1bgun0k0/9/

Comment: fails on multiple rows

Comment: Still fails on multiple *rows* :)

Comment: @Terry it's messed, resize the window till Gamma is in the new line. click before it. See?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1bgun0k0/10/ Updated the fiddle to better debug the multiline solution

Comment: @Terry: just click on the left side of the div (in a new fiddle from my comment above) until a new row appears. Click on the left side of the second row or the right side of the first one. New element is added to the wrong row.

Comment: This is my favorite solution so far. I prefer a bit more JS (within reason) to extra layout. I hope it could be adapted to a multi-row case without doubling the code length. :)

Comment: That's probably because of the nature of the inline-block element. If you prevent the line from breaking itself, that would probably work.