# How to find pseudo element (e.g. video::-webkit-media) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript (no jquery) to find an element so I add an event listener to the click event. I can alter the CSS with no trouble:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button { display: block !important; }', 1)
```

How would I use `document.getElementsByTagName()` or similar functions to fetch this dom element?

Comment: You can't, pseudo elements are not part of the DOM.

Comment: Pseudo-elements aren't actual DOM nodes, and can't be targeted with JS.

Comment: Is that considered a pseudo element? It is the play button that appears on iOS when viewing a video

Comment: It's pseudo-class, doesn't matter. You can't.

Comment: got it thanks guys

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element

Comment: In any case you don't really need it. Just query element by classes, tags, ids, attributes, etc.