# jquery - How to select: .editfield:hover:after

Tags: jquery, select

This is my style (bubble appears on hover with "Edit / Éditer" inside):

```
.editfield:hover:after {
content: "Edit / Éditer";
position:absolute;
padding:10px;
font-size:0.7em;
background-color: #FFC;
color: #999;
border-radius:10px;
border:solid 1px #999;
left:45%;   
z-index:12000;
}
```

I want a function to be triggered when the bubble is clicked. So I need to know how to select that bubble.

I saw this reply that works for title but it does not work here even if it is adapted:

```
$(".class[title='whatever']")
```

Comment: $(".editfield:hover:after").click(function() <-- this does not work either

Comment: pseudo-elements do not accept events

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element

Comment: thanks - there is a solution for me there...