# Pseudoelement selector for inserting icon inside of another element

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-element

I would like to use some pseudo-element selector (:before, :after) for including a text or icon on :hover inside some other element. Is there a way how to do that only with pseudo-element selectors? I would like to **NOT actually change the content of that element** as it's content is loaded from `localStorage`.

My vision is to visually add some click-able icon (✗, ) when hovering over the header.

```
<header contenteditable="true" id="title" onkeyup="store(this.id);"></header>
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you wanted something like this ?

you can also use fontAwesome in the `after` element or a background-image.

```css
header {
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 position:relative;
 background:Red;
}
header:after {
 content:"X";
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 color:#fff;
 transition:0.3s ease-out;
 opacity:0;
}
header:hover:after {
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<header contenteditable="true" id="title" onkeyup="store(this.id);"></header>
```

**option2**. using plain Javascript

added the fontAwesome icon using javascript ( `beforeend` = inserted right before the end of the `header` tag -> you can use `beforebegin,afterbegin,beforeend,afterend` see more here [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) )

then, you can add a click event on the previously added icon. ( here i am toggling the class of header changing it's color )

let me know if it helps

```js
var newElem = document.getElementById("title");

newElem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i id="clickme" class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>');

document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function() {

  newElem.classList.toggle('blue');
};
```

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: Red;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

header:hover .fa {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

header.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header contenteditable="true" id="title" onkeyup="store(this.id);"></header>
```

Comment: Would the `X` be able to have some action on itself? Should I specify that in the content? Thank you.

Comment: you cannot access pseudo elements with Jquery so it won't be able to have any action. you could add an element with Jquery and then give that element an action. do you want that ?

Comment: I thought a solution without the need for jQuery would exist. Would something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23243996/6018512 be possible to use here?

Comment: @BBerry as you can see in that answer, javascript is used. so you can't use just css for this. are you ok in using javascript ?

Comment: I have nothing against using plain JavaScript:D That is that in the answer, is it not? I would just rather not use the jQuery. If that even makes sense.

Comment: @BBerry i provided a new plain javascript solution. see if you like it

Answer (score 2):

You can add your icon as `background-image` .

```
 header{
 position:relative;
 }

 header:before{
 content:" ";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:5px;
 height:5px;
 background: url(icon.png) no-repeat ;

 }
```

Comment: This would be better if you can provide a sample code

Comment: @Swellar i was on it. :)

Comment: Could background-image have some JavaScript action defined when clicked? Or would that be overridden by the clicking the editable content of the header?

Comment: @BBerry it seems possible.check second best answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element

Answer (score 0):

try using the content attribute in the pseudo selectors or add it as a background image