# Table cell corners highlighting - html/css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have defined two CSS classes that highlights corners of table cells:

```
   .right
   {
       background-image: linear-gradient(225deg, green, green 5px, transparent 5px, transparent);
   }
   .left
   {
       background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, orange, orange 5px, transparent 5px, transparent);
   }
```

(example of usage)

```
<td /*some attributes*/ class="right">value</td>
```

When I use it for table cells, it looks like this:

[image]

But both of them sets background so I can't use both of them to the same cell. Is here any way how to highlight both corners of the same cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already solved this problem, I just made combined class

```
.note.approving
       {
           background-image: linear-gradient(225deg, green, green 5px, transparent 5px, transparent), linear-gradient(135deg, orange, orange 5px, transparent 5px, transparent);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution, using pseudo-elements to insert CSS triangles:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1.6em 1em;
}

td.left::before,
td.right::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

td.left::before {
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid orange;
}

td.right::after {
  right: -5px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">1</td>
    <td class="left right">2</td>
    <td class="right">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

While a lot more verbose than OP's own solution (using background gradients), this might have some additional value to some, seeing that the [pseudo elements could enable you to add pointer events to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32993828/3316645), depending on your exact scenario.

Comment: this works indeed, but that is very much CSS compare  to a single gradient rule ;) 1line against 20 lines dispatch in 2 selectors

Comment: Absolutely, I think the gradient version is indeed a much more elegant solution. Just wanted to provide this in addition to OP's solution, in case someone, one day, is looking to do the same but can't use `background` for whatever reason. Also, I kind of had to substantiate my comment. ;)

Comment: One benefit of this, by the way, is that you can do a bit more with it than with just background gradients. For example, [change the cursor to `pointer`, or possibly even put some JavaScript `onclick` on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element#comment39751366_7478344).

Comment: not too sure about onclick and javascript since pseudos are not part of the dom, but playing with pointer-events you might get to something / effects

Comment: This is the perfect solution for me because I'm already using background row colours. Thanks.