# Adding click event from jquery .class[data-attribute='value'] selector

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project where I am creating a 3 dot menu and want to add a click handler to.

I have the following HTML

```
<td z-var="ExceptionGroup @data-exception-group, CrashType @data-crash-type" data-exception-group="" data-crash-type="" class="context-menu" data-container-id="crash_group_menu"></td>
```

The above TD has the class context-menu which is as follows in CSS:

```
.context-menu:after
{
    content: '\2807';
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

I've then tried the following jquery to select the 3 dot item and set a click event on it:

```
$('.context-menu[data-container-id="crash_group_menu"]').click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
```

The click event never gets fired but there is no javascript error in the develop console.

I've also tried the following:

```
$('.context-menu[data-container-id="crash_group_menu"]:after').click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
```

(Notice I've added `:after` to the data-attribute selector) but no joy.

I've done this before when using div containers, is this not possible with class and data attribute selection or am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only detect click event on pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element)

Comment: Working in pure HTML : https://jsfiddle.net/06jx2n9r/ . Is your <td> in DOM on page load ?

Comment: I think I am being a numpty. The table is populated in the document.ready after an API call, I think the click event is being created before the table has been populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I said this in the comment but for others who may have had something similar.

The problem was the table was being populated dynamically via an API call. This then meant that I was attempting to add the click handler before the table was populated.

I got round this by using [javascript promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).

I return a promise for populating the table, once the promise has been completed successfully, I then create the click handler as needed.