# How do I change :before when hovering over another element?

Tags: html, css

First of all here's my code:

```css
body{
  background: #00BCD4;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="18" viewBox="0 0 100 18"%3E%3Cpath fill="%239C92AC" fill-opacity="0.4" d="M61.82 18c3.47-1.45 6.86-3.78 11.3-7.34C78 6.76 80.34 5.1 83.87 3.42 88.56 1.16 93.75 0 100 0v6.16C98.76 6.05 97.43 6 96 6c-9.59 0-14.23 2.23-23.13 9.34-1.28 1.03-2.39 1.9-3.4 2.66h-7.65zm-23.64 0H22.52c-1-.76-2.1-1.63-3.4-2.66C11.57 9.3 7.08 6.78 0 6.16V0c6.25 0 11.44 1.16 16.14 3.42 3.53 1.7 5.87 3.35 10.73 7.24 4.45 3.56 7.84 5.9 11.31 7.34zM61.82 0h7.66a39.57 39.57 0 0 1-7.34 4.58C57.44 6.84 52.25 8 46 8S34.56 6.84 29.86 4.58A39.57 39.57 0 0 1 22.52 0h15.66C41.65 1.44 45.21 2 50 2c4.8 0 8.35-.56 11.82-2z"%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
.conteiner{
  background: #E0F7FA;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.button{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 90px;
  width: 190px;
  background: #00ACC1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transition:  0.6s;
}

.button::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  background: #00B6CC;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.button::after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  background: #00A1B5;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.button:hover:after{
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  
}

.button:hover:before{
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.button:hover{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

i.fa-user{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 20%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
i.fa-cogs{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  right: 20%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
.button:hover  i{
  opacity: 1;
}
.fa-user:hover + .button:before{
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
</head>

<div class="conteiner">
  
  <a href="#" class="button">
  Hover me
   <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
  </a>
   
</div>
```

So, I have :before and :after pseudo elements on my .button (anchor). And I have some Font-Awesome icons that appear when the .button is hovered. Also my :before and :after take the full height and 45% width. 
So what I want to do is when the icon is hovered, that pseudo element, either :before or :after takes 90% width, and the other pseudo element gets pushed either to left or right.

But main question is how to I trigger pseudo elements to change when hovering over the icon.

Thank You.

Comment: You can't target a parent with CSS, so your hover needs to take place on your button or you'll need to make use of script.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7478344/1447509

Answer (score 0):

Since Pseudo elements are not actual DOM elements so hover will not get apply on this directly.

But if you need to change width of hovered icon you can put icon in some real DOM element e.g `<span>`,  etc, then apply hover effect.