# Select ::before element using javascript or creating a div inside another div javascript

Tags: javascript

Please see my html

```
<style>
.my-div::before{
  content:'click me';
  display:block;
  border:1px solid black;
 }
</style>

<div class="my-div">....</div>
```

Now what I need is when someone clicking the click me function then I have to redirect to another page using javascript. How can I do this?

or **I have to create a new button inside the my-div using javascript**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only detect click event on pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this in the following way:

Add pointer events to your `.my-div` element so the main element has `pointer-events: none` and the pseudo element `::before` has `pointer-events: all`.

Then add a click listener to the `.my-div` element.

Code below

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')[0].addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Click'));
```

```html
<style>
.my-div {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.my-div::before{
  content:'click me';
  display:block;
  border:1px solid black;
  pointer-events: all;
 }
</style>

<div class="my-div">....</div>
```

**Answer updated according to OP comments below**

If you want to add the button using only javascript and not the `::before` pseudo element you can do it this way:

```js
let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerHTML = "CLICK";
btn.id = "redirect-button";
document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')[0].appendChild(btn);

document.getElementById('redirect-button').addEventListener('click', () => window.location.href = "https://www.google.com");
```

```html
<div class="my-div">....</div>
```

See it working on: https://jsfiddle.net/dgw5ej9n/

Comment: Hi could you please help to  create a new button inside the my-div using javascript. Please see my updated question

Comment: So, you dont want the `::before` element to be the button, You want to add the button using Javascript?

Comment: yes please . i want to create an extra button or div