# Add event listener to ::after with javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, addeventlistener

I have to add an event listener to an `::after` element using javascript.
I guess I have to select it doing something like:

```
var varName = document.querySelector('#myElementId::after');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: No, it's not possible, as the `before` and `after` pseudo-elements don't exist in the DOM.

Comment: you cannot target ::before or ::aftter pseudoelement for click events. The best you can do is attach the click handler onto the parent element that houses the elements

Comment: check this link. I think you can find your answer from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element

Comment: Thank you very much