# How to overlay an icon image on multiple images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I need to add an expand icon on top of a number of existing images. The image is displayed as a thumbnail and expands when clicked. The expand icon is to indicate that the images are clickable. I have the following implementation, but it's not ideal. It would be great if I didn't have to add the `<img src="expand-icon.png" class="img-expand" />` on each and every image. I tried adding the icon using the `::after` property, but the icon was not clickable and the position ended below the image not on top.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <img src="my-image-that-will-expand-when-clicked.png" class="thumbnail" />
    <img src="expand-icon.png" class="img-expand" />
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .thumbnail {
        thumbnail-max-height: auto;
        thumbnail-max-width: 500px;
        thumbnail: popup;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .thumbnail-container {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px solid #858383;
        border-radius: 9px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .img-expand {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        max-width: 20px;
        pointer-events: none
    }
```

And, there is a JS script that runs in the background. I don't have access to that script, the tool runs it in the background.

Comment: In my opinion it makes perfect sense for each image to have it's own expand button. Is there a reason you need to avoid it?

Comment: *"I tried adding the icon using the ::after property"* This should work. If you show us that it would be helpful. Sounds like you did not position the pseudo element properly.

Comment: @anpel we have 100s of images, so it's not ideal to copy/paste the code all over, and would be a nuisance if we need to update it at some point.

Comment: @Paulie_D I got rid of all the pseudo-codes, but I will try to recreate it and update my post.

Comment: @user12011325 the idea here is that you have some sort of array with images and some sort of templating engine and you maintain the code only once - no need to copy / paste the markup over and over.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add the expand icon by using `::after` like you said in your question. This sounds like a good approach. The reason it didn't work is either due to poor positioning or no content being displayed.
Remember to either set `content: "";` or `content: url(...);` and then set `pointer-events: all;` in your pseudo-element.

Here is an example:

```
.thumbnail::after {
    content: url(expand-icon.png);
    pointer-events: all;
    /* set size and position however you like... */
}
```

However, with this approach your pseudo element is still [not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element), and you will have to manage click events for the entire image as there is no way to tell between the image and its child pseudo-element.
You could use empty `span` or `div` elements and position them as clickable areas, but at this point you've gone too far.

In the end, if you absolutely must make *only* the button clickable, there is no easy work-around using pseudo-elements and you will have to use your current setup with two images.

An elegant solution, would be to use the pseudo-element and make the entire **image** clickable. Or if you want a part of it clickable, you can maybe use a `map`, but I recommend against doing this.