# How to make a ::before image clickable

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to get the effect seen on many sites where on hover an image appears that is clickable. For example, when an element is hovered over the bin image appears using ::before. I would like to make this clickable.

[image]

The image is displayed on the section div using:

```
.section:hover::before {
  content: url("@/assets/icons/bin.svg");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I understand from reading many similar posts that the pseudo element itself does not allow for this but I am wondering how this effect is achieved.

Comment: You can do this with JS...

Comment: @Zain Any further explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element pls check here it might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

simply add an `<a>` tag with href pointing to where you want...