# Can I know if the click event in JS was produced while the cursor was pointer?

Tags: javascript, css, events, click

I'll explain: I want to detect a click on a pseudo-element, which I already know is not possible. So I've thought that I could made the cursor pointer with CSS while the cursor is over the pseudo-element and then, when the click event starts, watch if the cursor was pointer at that moment.

Comment: Can you please upload code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only detect click event on pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element)