# Div with a slanted bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a container for my website and have it be slightly slanted on the bottom like so:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? I tried `transform: skewy(-10deg);` but it does the top too which I'm trying not to do.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slanted">HI</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slanted {
    background-color:red;
    height:500px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? If there is no content and you just need the color, you could rotate the colored item and apply `overflow:hidden` to the parent element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-tone background split by diagonal line using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739162/two-tone-background-split-by-diagonal-line-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. Just wanted the top and the bottom part to not be slanted so I added some negative margin.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.first {
  margin-top: -45px;
}

.slanted {
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-transform: skewy(-3deg);
  transform: skewy(-3deg);
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -45px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<section class="slant-container">
  <div class="slanted first" style="background-color:#2ecc71;"></div>
  <div class="slanted" style="background-color:#3498db;"></div>
  <div class="slanted" style="background-color:#f39c12;"></div>
</section>

<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 14):

**HTML**

```
<div class="slanted">HI</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slanted {
    background-color:red;
    height:500px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 56%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
}
```

**CodePen**

http://codepen.io/anthonyastige/pen/PzWvqo

**Reference**

[Angled Edges with CSS Masks and Transforms](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms)

Answer (score 0):

Refer below snippet, this might e\be useful to you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .updatedDiv {
                border-top-color: transparent; 
                border-right-color: rgb(7, 133, 214); 
                border-top-width: 59px; 
                border-right-width: 110px; 
                border-top-style: solid; 
                border-right-style: solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div  class="updatedDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work with content in it - http://codepen.io/anthonyastige/pen/YWNbqb

Comment: we can have two div's. one to show slanted div and another for contents