# Overlay trapezium shape on DIV

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Trying to get this design using CSS.

[image]

The parts are as follows:

1. has a `background image`
2. is a trapezium with a transparent `background` with horizontal text

I've taken a look at [Two-tone background split by diagonal line using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739162/two-tone-background-split-by-diagonal-line-using-css) but am still a bit stumped.

CSS is not a strong point!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Kind of looks like a skewed div `#theDiv{ border:3px solid black; transform: skew(0,-10deg); } with span-text absolutely positioned over #theDiv.

Comment: Have a look at this site: http://www.oca.nz/ it's using this a lot

Comment: Quick demo using just two elements: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hqhmx78e/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @markE mentioned a good way to achieve this is using `skew`

Use `position:relative` in `.wrap` and `position:absolute` in the parallelogram `div` to achieve the overlay effect (using the `rgba` in `background` property)

Note: this is a parallelogram, not a trapezium - this might help you on future searches

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("//lorempixel.com/1200/600")
}
.parallelogram {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  transform: skew(0, -15deg);
}
span {
  display: block;
  transform: skew(0, 15deg);
  margin: 70px 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parallelogram"><span>title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 title 1 </span>
  </div>
</div>
```