# Give multiple colors to a button using css

Tags: css

I Want to color a button just like this. Is there any way i can do this by using css?

[Button should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPSpE.jpg)

Comment: create a custom button

Comment: I found this other stackoverflow question that is similar that looks like it has a good response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739162/two-tone-background-split-by-diagonal-line-using-css Should be a good starting point!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-tone background split by diagonal line using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739162/two-tone-background-split-by-diagonal-line-using-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using something like this

```css
.x{
height: 50px;
background: #ff3232;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%, #ff3030 50%, #282fff 51%, #005dff 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 50%,#282fff 51%,#005dff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 50%,#282fff 51%,#005dff 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#005dff',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a linear gradient.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/sy1mtqe3/)

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(-60deg, red 50%, yellow 50%);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="main"></button>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(255, 0, 144), rgb(255, 0, 144) 55%, rgb(0, 222, 255), rgb(0, 222, 255) 45%);
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/MatthewMob/pen/aJOBPN)