# Divide a rectangle into 2 triangles along diagonal using css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div into 2 triangles (as shown in below, no problem if 1 is background of parent) upper one with one color and lower one with another. I dont mind how it is implemented but i want to do it in css (not javascript). I tried with css rotation, (code below), but its not responsive. In smaller or wider screen it is distorted . Any way to implement this in css?

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.darker {
  position: fixed;
  top: -94%;
  left: -10%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  background: #dd4f39;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="darker">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work

Comment: Do you want to show any content inside these triangles?

Comment: no , no contents. just a responsive way to do this .

Comment: i know about the  css triangles . but in this case i m trying to do it responsive  . css triangle need border-width in pixels  so cant really implement using css triangles

Comment: Sometimes google is not a bad idea: https://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/

Comment: i did google it but u just gave me the same thing i just said . this implementation needs border-width to be in pixel css doesnt support border-width in % so it wont be responsive

Comment: so when i attach this div to body it wont be responsive  , if im using triangle as u mentiond above.

Comment: is viewport width an option?

Comment: if it's see if thiss will work https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/kqsrmrss/

Comment: @karthick this is great but if i can controll the height also it would be better.

Comment: @Jayakrishnan you can control the height. All you have to do is give the same height value to the border-top in the pseudo

Comment: so for full size i have to use some jquery like ` $('div').after().height($(window).height());`  ? .

Comment: @karthick thanks btw. Actually your slightly modified code works perfect for my current context .

Comment: you can give 100vh

Comment: @karthick If you post that fiddle you have my upvote...clever done using border

Comment: @LGSon Sure thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two-tone background split by diagonal line using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739162/two-tone-background-split-by-diagonal-line-using-css)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an interesting way to do this from [here](https://youtu.be/QY7Rj8aZcZk?t=735), which uses [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
 .Answering my own question so that everyone can use it.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

.box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #dd4f39;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

This is one way of doing it. But this use case is strictly with respect to vw. Just make sure to give the same value to these elements

div and it's pseudo element should have same width and border-left respectively.
div and it's pseudo element should have same height and border-top respectively.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.box::after {
  content: ' ';
  border-top: 100vh solid #dd4f39;
  border-left: 100vw solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kqsrmrss/2/

Comment: Made a small change, hope it was okay ...and +1

Comment: @LGSon Thanks. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a skewed pseudo element. The main trick is to keep the aspect ratio the same or else the sloped angle will fail

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9qts8919/1/)

Stack snippet <sup>Note 1</sup>

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.darker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: #dd4f39;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.darker::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  transform: skewY(26.5deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="darker"></div>
```

---

Optionally, you can add media query to control the angle at different screen sizes

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/9qts8919/2/)

---

With a tiny script running when window resize's, you can control the angle and make it fully responsive both horizontally and vertically.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup> Based on a comment, the Stack snippet might not work properly, and if, try the fiddle demos.

Comment: Your fiddle demo works, the snippet view did not unless I go full view

Comment: also u cant change height

Comment: @mplungjan Strange...for me both works...in Chrome/Win 10

Comment: @Jayakrishnan No you can't, using CSS this is what you can get. With script or SVG you can get both

Comment: i know i can use svg . but im just asking here to know if there is a different way to do it

Comment: @Jayakrishnan To solve it with CSS you need to use CSS Calc, but since it does not support _squareroot_, you can't calc the angle

Comment: @Jayakrishnan With my second fiddle, you'll see that with some media queries you can get closer

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code snippet.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.diagonalRising {
  border: 1pt solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #eeeeee 0%, #eeeeee 49.9%, #eeeeee 50%, #000000 51%, #dd4f39 51.1%, #dd4f39 100%);
}

.diagonalFalling {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #eeeeee 0%, #eeeeee 49.9%, #000000 50%, #000000 51%, #dd4f39 51.1%, #dd4f39 100%);
}

.diagonalCross {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 49.9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 51.1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}

.diagonalCross:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 49.9%, #000000 50%, #000000 51%, #ffffff 51.1%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonalRising"></div>
<div class="diagonalFalling"></div>
<div class="diagonalCross"></div>
```

Comment: And how to dynamically follow resize?

Comment: You can resize div element by jQuery and jQery UI library.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#div_id" ).resizable();
  } );
  </script>

Comment: I meant your squares are static. They need to resize when the window is

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.box::after {
    background:  #E52A35
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #dd4f39;
    clip-path: polygon(52% 13%, 104% -1%, -1% 0%);
}
```