# Create HTML/CSS Box with Three Diagonal Colors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a square that has three colors similar to [Two-tone background split by diagonal line using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739162/two-tone-background-split-by-diagonal-line-using-css) but instead of just two colors, three more like this:

[image: Block of three diagonal colors]

Any advice? I tried this:

```css
.diagonal-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.diagonal-box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 200px 200px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #FF7F50;
}

.diagonal-box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 200px 200px 0;
  border-color: transparent #00BFFF transparent;
}

.diagonal-box div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
  border-color: #7CFC00 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal-box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

but it does not correctly put the triangles in the way that I want.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a simple solution requiring no extra `div` or `before` and `after` pseudo-elements:

```
.diagonal-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff7f50 0% 35%, #7cfc00 35% 65%, #00bbff 65% 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem ?
I've used `clip-path` to make those simple triangles rather than using invisible borders. You can tweak the width of the triangles' short sides by changing the `--width` value.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Box with Three Diagonal Colors</title>
  <style>
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .diagonal-box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .diagonal-box::before,
    .diagonal-box::after {
      position: absolute;
      inset: 0;
      /* this is the same as top, right, bottom, left : 0*/
      content: "";
    }

    .diagonal-box::before {
      --width: 160px;
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, var(--width) 0, 0 var(--width));
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .diagonal-box::after {
      --width: 160px;
      clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% calc(100% - var(--width)), calc(100% - var(--width)) 100%);
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="diagonal-box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can even declare `--width` in `.diagonal-box` if you want both triangles to automatically have the same width ;)