# Detect click how far to the left inside a div

Tags: jquery

Say I have a div that is 200px wide, I want after I click for example in the middle to log in the console 100px, and so on (If i click 20px to the right of the left edge I would like to log 20 for example)

Is this possible and any pointers?

Comment: downvote is probably cause you show no effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: If I understood, you want the position in pixels where did you click?

Comment: It would be a legitimate question if you had shown some effort in trying to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: It also doesn't help to show hostility on a site populated by volunteers (comment now deleted)

Comment: Yes, it's possible using JavaScript. What have you tried? We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: I always show effor when I ask but in this instance i really can't. The answer is like 1 line of code.

Comment: [Searching for 'jquery click coordinates' would've been faster anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234977/using-jquery-how-to-get-click-coordinates-on-the-target-element).

Comment: I did try searching but didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KrJ7b/

```
$('#mydiv').on('click',function(e){
      console.log(e.clientX - $(this).offset().left);    
});
```