# Click a certain area of a video and change video time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have an html5 video and I'd like to make it interactive. If a user clicks on a certain area of the video (let's say top left area), that makes the video time changes -> currenttime=60 (just an example)

If he clicks on the bottom right area, currenttime=138. How can I do that?

I know I need to create an overlay div and make it clickable but I really need some help with that.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Check the info here. And do some fancy math to find the "quadrant" you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234977/using-jquery-how-to-get-click-coordinates-on-the-target-element

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't think I need coordinates and stuff like that because I just need to click on a div not an exact coordinate. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well then its just `$('#divID').click(function() { YOUR CODE });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give an example of changing it to 3seconds, you can understand from it how to make it 60 or 138. In jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jyFU/

If doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<video id="video1" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<div id="time_3" onclick="setCurTime()"></div>

      <script>
          myVid=document.getElementById("video1");
function setCurTime()
  { 
  myVid.currentTime=3;
  }
      </script>

      <p> Press the top-left part of the video to make it jump to 3 seconds.</p>
```

CSS:

```
#video1{
    width:500px;
    position:absolute;
}
#time_3{
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:125px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

p {
    margin-top:170px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was asking. Thanks thanks thanks.