# How to draw divs to a specific position using jQuery UI 's selectable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to draw divs to a specific position using jQuery UI's `selectable`,

I've tried it and I thought it's almost figured out:
http://jsfiddle.net/62LJG/

The steps I've thought is:

1. Fetch `Selectable`'s helper's `left` and `top`.
2. Fetch `Selectable`'s helper's `width` and `height`.
3. Append a div to my target and I can use these `left`, `top`, `width`, `height` I've got to CSS this div.

Now my problem is I can't get the width and height from this widget.

I thought all the jQuery UI are similar so I tried this:

```
$('#tar').selectable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.size.width + ',' + ui.size.height);
  }
});
```

but this part `ui.size` doesn't work.

But I can use `ui.size` in jQuery `resizable` or `draggable` to get width and height.

How can I get `width` and `height` from jQuery `selectable`'s helper(dotted line) to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out.

`event.page - position()` will get the relative value.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/62LJG/1/

reference: [Using jQuery how to get click coordinates on the target element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234977/using-jquery-how-to-get-click-coordinates-on-the-target-element)

Answer (score 0):

The ui object seems to be empty, use this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tar').selectable({
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(this).width() + ',' + $(this).height());
      }
    });
});
```

If you have padding/margin in your element use $(this).outerWidth() and $(this).outerHeight().

Comment: I used this just now.
but I got the width and height from #tar (300, 300)

Comment: I want to fetch width and height from the selectable's helper(dotted line)

anyway, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: you mean to draw a div inside?

Comment: Yes, I want to draw a div inside of #tar.