# How to output text next to where you click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table which its outputting about 1k records.

since there are many records I have to click down to view them all,
but when I do scroll down and I click on the name it shows the output at the same
place on top.

How can I get it that it can show the text next to where I click in on the browser without scrolling up?

I made a http://jsfiddle.net/xhow5n44/ .
 I'm not sure if this is something that will be easier to make  it happen with css or javascript.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('a').click(function () {
         var StateName = $(this).attr("detail");
         $('#maintext').show();
         $('#output').html(StateName);
     });
 });
</script>

<table class="tablecolors">
      <thead><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Ext:</th><th scope="col">Title </th></thead>
        <tbody>
        <cfloop query="Corporate"  >
        <cfoutput>
        <tr>
        <td ><a  id="showdata"  detail="Cell:<cfif  #Corporate.emp_cell# eq ""> No Number<cfelse>#Corporate.emp_cell# </cfif> 
        <br/>test">
        #Corporate.emp_namefirst#       
        <td ><div align="center">#Corporate.emp_ext#</div></td>
        <td > <cfif #Corporate.title_id# is not 19>#Corporate.title_name#</cfif> </td>

        </tr>
        </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>

        </tbody>
</table>

    <h2 id="maintext" style="display: none;">Here We will Display </h2>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [following Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3236129/4151333) to get the mouse position. Once you have it, you can use it to position your text based on that values via CSS and jQuery.

```
$(elem)
  .css('left', value_x + 'px')
  .css('top', value_y + 'px');
```

**Edit** 
As noticed by Roko in the comments, the code above can be improved by using object notation like

```
$(elem).css({
  'top':  value_y,
  'left': value_x
});
```

Comment: You probably mean .css()... Also use object notation, and also "px" is not needed cause it's px by default.

Comment: Yeah, sure i ment `.css()` and not `.style()`. I looked in some of my code and forgot that I used another framework there.