# Offset seems to be drasticly different per item i click

Tags: html, css

I have been working with creating a selection box around some cells,  The selection box is absolute so it can reach everywhere it needs to, to create a click and drag box around some cells.

It seems that based on the mousedown event, the position of the box is set correctly for class `hour` but not for `half-hour`.  While it is the same code, `hour` offset will return me the corrdinates of the item. relative to the doc, whereas the `half-hour` will return approx (0,6) which sets the top:left to the upper right corner.

Right now, my dom looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell hour">
    <div class="half-hour"></div>
    <div class="half-hour"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.hour{
  position:relative;
}
.half-hour{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

From what it looks like is that the offset I am getting when selecting the `half-hour` is the offset to the parent `hour` and the `hour` i think is getting his relative to the page?

After looking at these, I was thinking that setting `half-hour` to: *position:relative;` might do the trick, but it didnt do anything.  it is the same.

I am thinking i need to modify something. im just not sure what.

I will eventually be doing this same design for a class called: `quarter-hour` which will have 2 in each of the `half-hour` divs.

**Edit** based on the question below, I just have a simple:  ` which is on the page, and then on mousedown it would:

1- Set Top:Left values based on mouse.target.offsetTop && mouse.target.offsetLeft respectively.

2- Set position absolute (though it should be already)

3- set dimensions, Height and Width accordingly.

**Edit 2**  I managed to recreate my issue with this fiddle    https://jsfiddle.net/838vqboe/  I am currently giving 3 options in the DDL.   Hour works as expected, but not HH or QH.

Comment: 1. Where in the above markup is the selection box? .. or you add it dynamically on click? ... 2. How does its markup/CSS look like?

Comment: I have a div with `position: absolute` i add to the page.  Then I would set its position and dimensions dynamically.  It just seems that right now:  in my event handler:  mouse.target.offsetLeft &&  mouse.target.offsetTop is not returning the dimensions i was expecting.  I was expecting something similar to more defined based on the document, not the parent.

Comment: So it appears you get the wrong coordinates, and since we can't see the code?, does this one give some answers how and what to expect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234977/using-jquery-how-to-get-click-coordinates-on-the-target-element

Comment: This doesnt seem to really solve it.  Let me see about getting an example up and running.

Comment: updatd with a js fiddle.

Comment: i ended up copying the output from my dom-repeater, but the fix should really just be somewhere in mousedown OR in the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with a solution which worked in Javascript, but when converting it to Dart, specifically with Polymer, the concepts behind shadowdom was alien to me.  This I think is the issue I was having as it was determining a local root it was applying positions to while the mouse gave me positions in relation to the screen.

To resolve this, I noticed that something which extends PolymerElement has get getBoundingClientRect(), so i ended up doing something like the following in javascript:

```
var _mouseDown = function(e){
  var selectedHtml = e.target;
  var left = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().left - getBoundingClientRect().left
  var top = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().top - getBoundingClientRect().top 
  _selectionDiv.css({left:left, top:top});
}
$selection.on("mousedown", _mouseDown);
```

and in Dart:

```
Function _mouseDown(MouseEvent mouse){
  HtmlElement selectedElement =- mouse.target;
  var left = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().left - getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var top = selectedHtml.getBoundingClientRect().top - getBoundingClientRect().top ;
  _selectionDiv.style.top = "${top}px";
  _selectionDiv.style.left = "${left}px";
}
```