# Non integer offset positions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, pixel, offset

jQuerys offset function sometimes returns rational numbers (like 12.645613) for top or left. I thought that top and left positions are in pixels and so should be integers (there are no half pixel, or?).

Comment: Really? Can you show an example?

Comment: And what functions returns such a number?

Comment: Go to http://www.dotnetoutsource.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/jQuery_FixedTable_Demo.htm and then `$(".fixedColumn").eq(0).offset().top` results in my Firefox with 182.5833282470703

Comment: Well in Chrome it is just 180.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top and left positions can be floating point numbers with any of the units cm, mm, in, pt, pc, em, ex or px, or percentages.

Example:

```
.someElement { top: 42%; left: 3.14in; }
```

The `offset` function returns the position translated into pixels, so that can very well be a floating point number. The values are not rounded.

With the example given, if the height of the parent would for example be 32 pixels, the `top` value of the element would be 32 * 0.42 = 13.44 pixels.

Comment: Then this sounds to me like a jQuery bug in my case as the documentation about offset says: "Get the current coordinates". What you describe is more where it should be and not where it currently really is.

Comment: @Zardoz: Well, that depends on how you see it. Where the element "is", is not neccesarily where the browser choose to display it, i.e. it's coordinates is floating point but it's usually displayed at an even pixel. Most browsers has a 1:1 relationship between their coordinate systems and the screen pixels, but the iphone 4 for example has a 1:2 relationship, so it could actually place elements at half pixels.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but I guess I could post an answer here, for posterity.

I was having this issue too, and I found out (thanks Firebug) that the problem lies in that the h1 and h3 tags have floating point margins (for instance, Firefox by default gives `<H1>` a `0.67em 0` margin).

When you delete the `<H1>` and `<H3>` tags `$(".fixedColumn").eq(0).offset().top` returns an integer. You could just specify margins for those tags and the problem should be fixed.