# Hover to move slider left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('#next').hover(function () {
    $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
    }, "fast");
});

$('#prev').hover(function () {
    $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
    }, "fast");
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/roe4ep78/). I'm trying to get the scrolling to be continuous while hovering .hover() function isn't working properly or as I thought it would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this help you

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jm33rjtj/)

```
function loopNext(){
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop().animate({scrollLeft:'+=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopNext);
}

function loopPrev(){
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop().animate({scrollLeft:'-=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopPrev);
}

function stop(){
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop();
}


$('#next').hover(function () {
   loopNext();
},function () {
   stop();
});

$('#prev').hover(function () {
   loopPrev();
},function () {
   stop();
});
```

Source: [Continuous scroll on hover [performance]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219649/continuous-scroll-on-hover-performance)

Comment: Works great thank you so much! Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/88hv1hvs/)!

Comment: @adrxlm: my answer was wrong,i first thought your answer was same as that i answered..!! but you have answered it really well

Answer (score 4):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roe4ep78/6/)

This will, on the `next` hover, start animating towards the `width` of the containing `div`.  When you mouse out, it will stop.  On the `prev` hover will start animating to `0` and when you mouse out it will stop.

```
$('#next').hover(function () {  
    $('#sliderWrapper').animate({scrollLeft: $(this).siblings("#sliderWrapper").width()}, 5000);
}, function() {
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop();
});

$('#prev').hover(function () {  
    $('#sliderWrapper').animate({scrollLeft: 0 }, 5000);
}, function() {
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using the mouse over and out events. When the mouse goes over start animating and when the mouse goes out stop animating.

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: Even though I don't have mouseout implemented I still don't get the desired effect, instead it only moves it over 200px once. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/eoyd9tnq/).