# How to detect that the mouse is over an element during a scroll?

Tags: jquery

jQuery's mouseenter doesn't seem to fire when the mouse entered an element because of a scroll (i.e., as a result of scrolling).

Imagine the mouse pointer is currently *not* inside an element. Then you scroll using the scroll-wheel, resulting in the mouse pointer (which has not moved at all) being inside the element. jQuery will not fire the mouseenter callback. How can I get the mouseenter callback to fire in this case?

See http://mobdealio.com/131/?view=LIST&city=3 for an example. My idea is to update the map on the left when the user mouse's over a deal. But if the user scrolls using the scroll-wheel, then the map doesn't update (unless the user nudges the mouse a tiny bit).

Edit: I experience this issue in Chrome 15.0.874.121 m & Windows 7.

Comment: Not in chrome, though. I don't think there's anyway of doing it, apart from Adam's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing i can think of is to detect when the document is scrolled with `$(window).scroll`, and then get the cursor position relative to the element (this question was asked here: [jQuery get mouse position within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)) and if it is inside any of the elements then to change the map.

Comment: Thanks, dude. Sounds reasonable. I'll try this, and if it works, I'll mark this as the correct answer!