# Mouse position inside autoscaled SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I am experiencing troubles concerning the position of mouse cursor inside my SVG document. I'd like to design a potentiometer that will follow the cursor when dragged, using **JavaScript** in an HTML page.

I tried `evt.clientX/Y` and `evt.screenX/Y` but as my SVG is in **autoscale**, coordinates inside my SVG are different. I have been searching for an answer for days now but I couldn't find any solution (either knowing my SVG rescaling factor in real time or have a function for mouse location in SVG coordinates system).

The rotation will follow a simple rule:

```
if (evt.screenX < xc)
  ang = Math.atan((evt.screenY - yc) / (evt.screenX - xc)) * 360/(2*Math.PI) - 90;  

if (evt.screenX > xc)
  ang = Math.atan((evt.screenY - yc) / (evt.screenX - xc)) * 360/(2*Math.PI) + 90;
```

With `(xc;yc)` as center of rotation and replacing all `evt.screenX/Y` by the coordinates of the mouse inside my SVG.

Comment: you must work with the transformation matrix to get the correct coordinates. A jsfiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

See this code, which not only shows how to transform from screen space to global SVG space, but also how to transform a point from SVG space into the transformed space of an element:
http://phrogz.net/svg/drag_under_transformation.xhtml

In short:

```
// Find your root SVG element
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

// Create an SVGPoint for future math
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

// Get point in global SVG space
function cursorPoint(evt){
  pt.x = evt.clientX; pt.y = evt.clientY;
  return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

svg.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
  var loc = cursorPoint(evt);
  // Use loc.x and loc.y here
},false);
```

**Edit**: I've created a sample tailored to your needs (albeit only in global SVG space):
http://phrogz.net/svg/rotate-to-point-at-cursor.svg

It adds the following method to the above:

```
function rotateElement(el,originX,originY,towardsX,towardsY){
  var angle = Math.atan2(towardsY-originY,towardsX-originX);
  var degrees = angle*180/Math.PI + 90;
  el.setAttribute(
    'transform',
    'translate('+originX+','+originY+') ' +
      'rotate('+degrees+') ' +
      'translate('+(-originX)+','+(-originY)+')'
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I didn't respond earlier, the fact is that I couldn't, using firefox (I don't know why). So I see your code works separatly, but I'm still dealing with some strange issues, I'll come back to you as soon as I find a way to make it work in my project ! Thanks

Comment: It seems that my getBBox() is not working as it should, so I can't get the proper origin point that you use (I need this to be automatic so that the element can be easily moved with inkscape, and even copied/pasted to another svg). I've been trying many things but nothing worked.

Comment: @Riwall I suggest that you make a new question for your BBox issue; please be sure to include a simple, pared-down test case (in code in the question or JSFiddle) that reproduces your problem, and describe the OS/browser/version giving you trouble.

Comment: It's extremely useful! Maybe it's worth noting that every SVG DOM element has a `getScreenCTM()` method, so it can be used to transform mouse event `clientX` and `clientY` values into element-local coordinates!

Comment: I know this should not be written as a comment, but: "thank-you very much!". I've been struggling with a similar problem for weeks until I found your answer. Now my code works perfectly!

Comment: `document.rootElement` is the root SVG element, no need to use `querySelector`.

Comment: @osvein That is true when the document is an SVG file, but not when the document is an HTML that may include an SVG file. Note that if you need an SVG element just for `createSVGPoint()` you can also `svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');`

Answer (score 4):

@Phrogz: Thanks for your wonderful example and I learned from that. I have changed some of it like below to make it a bit easy right. As I thinking that like we handle mouse events in core java we can also handle same way here so I tried my way in your example.

I have removed "rotateElement" function as I think that it is some difficult and i find a substitute if it.

See below code:

```
var svg=document.getElementById("svg1");
var pt=svg.createSVGPoint();
var end_small=document.getElementById("end_small");
var line=document.getElementById("line1");

end_small.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {

    var loc=getCursor(evt);
    end_small.setAttribute("cx",loc.x);
    end_small.setAttribute("cy",loc.y);

    loc = getCursor(evt); // will get each x,y for mouse move

    line.setAttribute('x2',loc.x); // apply it  as end points of line
    line.setAttribute('y2',loc.y); // apply it as end points of line

}, false);

function getCursor(evt) {
    pt.x=evt.clientX;
    pt.y=evt.clientY;
    return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

So what I have done is I have just added listener only to small circle not whole SVG and everytime when mouse moved by you I will get `x, y` from `getCursor()` function as stated above and I will give this `x, y` as `x2, y2` of my line thats it does not translate and does not rotate. You must move your mouse to to circle and then slowly move and if your mouse leave circle then line will not move as we have just added listener only on small circle right.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the correct svg mouse coordinate is tricky. First of all, a common way is to use the clientX and clientY of the event property an substract it with getBoundingClientRect() and clientLeft respectively clientTop.

```
svg.addEventListener('click', event =>
{
    let bound = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

    let x = event.clientX - bound.left - svg.clientLeft - paddingLeft;
    let y = event.clientY - bound.top - svg.clientTop - paddingTop;
}
```

**But**, if the svg has a padding style information greater then zero, the coordinate is shifting. So this information must be also substract:

```
let paddingLeft = parseFloat(style['padding-left'].replace('px', ''));
let paddingTop = parseFloat(style['padding-top'].replace('px', ''));

let x = event.clientX - bound.left - svg.clientLeft - paddingLeft;
let y = event.clientY - bound.top - svg.clientTop - paddingTop;
```

And the not so nice think is, that in some browsers the border property also shift the coordinate, and in other not. I found out, that the shift takes place if the x and y of the event property is *not* available.

```
if(event.x === undefined)
{
    x -= parseFloat(style['border-left-width'].replace('px', ''));
    y -= parseFloat(style['border-top-width'].replace('px', ''));
}
```

After this transformation the x and y coordinate can out of bound, that should be fix. But that not the think.

```
let width = svg.width.baseVal.value;
let height = svg.height.baseVal.value;

if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height)
{
    return;
}
```

This solution can use for click, mousemove, mousedown, ... and so on.
You can reach a live demo here: https://codepen.io/martinwantke/pen/xpGpZB

Comment: what if svg has viewBox and width height does not match?

Answer (score 3):

Use [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) or [DOMPointReadOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPointReadOnly)

### Example

show cursor point on the SVG.

```html
<svg style="margin-left:35%; width:30%; border: 1px dashed blue">
  <text x="30" y="30">click me</text>
  <circle id="mouseCursor" cx="0" cy="0" r="4" fill="#00ff00" visibility="hidden"></circle>
</svg>
<script>
  const svg = document.querySelector(`svg`)

  svg.onclick = (e) => {
    const domPoint = new DOMPointReadOnly(e.clientX, e.clientY)
    const pt = domPoint.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse())
    const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`<circle cx="${pt.x}" cy="${pt.y}" r="2"></circle>`)
    svg.append(frag)
    svg.innerHTML = svg.innerHTML
  }

  // Below is for showing the cursor.
  svg.onmousemove = (e) => {
    const pt = new DOMPointReadOnly(e.clientX, e.clientY).matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse())
    const circleMouse = svg.querySelector(`#mouseCursor`)
    circleMouse.setAttribute("cx", `${pt.x}`)
    circleMouse.setAttribute("cy", `${pt.y}`)
  }
  svg.onmouseover = () => svg.querySelector(`#mouseCursor`).setAttribute("visibility", "visible")
  svg.onmouseout = () => svg.querySelector(`#mouseCursor`).setAttribute("visibility", "hidden")
</script>
```

> Note: [SVGPoint is **deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint)<sup>createSVGPoint</sup>. Use [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) or [DOMPointReadOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPointReadOnly) instead.