# javascript drawing with canvas offset

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, offset

First, I apologize for asking yet another question re canvas offsets. I see there are many related questions on stackoverflow, but I still couldn't solve my problem.

When I draw to canvas (see code below), it does not draw under the mouse cursor. It offsets to the right and down. I am expecting it to begin drawing under the mouse cursor.

Do I need to use any of these properties: Canvas offset? Event offset? ClientX? LayerX? OffsetLeft? OffsetTop?

```
move: function(event) {
  this.prevX = this.currX;
  this.prevY = this.currY;

  this.currX = event.clientX;
  this.currY = event.clientY;

  if (this.drawing) {
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.currX, this.currY);
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

Can someone please correct the bug in the jsfiddle below and explain why it works the way it does?

https://jsfiddle.net/f9trjzk5/4/

The JavaScript uses vue.js. It's what I'm learning now. If you are unfamiliar with it, just pretend it's not there. You'll see you have access to both the canvas and context variables -- `this.canvas`, `this.ctx`.

Thanks very much!

**UPDATE** The line is also clearly being drawn faster than the movement of the mouse....

**SOLVED** Needed to replace *style height and width properties* with *height and width attributes*
`style="height: 500px" width: 500px"` --> `height="500" width="500`
To quote the helpful answer I was given on the vuejs forum:

> What that does, is that is scales the canvas from its original (default) size up to match the width/height you've specified (like resizing an image, it becomes distorted). This is the same problem. That's why when moving the mouse to the right, it gets further and further away cos its a compounding effect.

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/canvas-drawing-wonky-under-vue-js-offset-all-weird/9028

Comment: What is the issue you're having when trying to draw to the canvas and what should happen?

Comment: It ain't drawing under the mouse. It draws off to the right and way down.

Comment: There is an issue with positioning in the canvas itself. The mouse positions are correct. But I am not sure, what went wrong here. I have also found a woking example in pure svg here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298658/mouse-position-inside-autoscaled-svg

Comment: @alpham8 My eyes glazed over when I saw matrices...

Comment: For the implementation of signatures within Vuejs I used signature_pad. Check it out: https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Comment: Thanks, @M.Suurland. I'll take a look!