# RevealJS and Highchart Mouse position Tooltip Issue

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, reveal.js

I've just built my first RevealJS presentation and while all seemed to work at glance I ran into an game breaking issue with a HighChart that is caused by the way RevealJS scales/moves and elements and SVG related (at least I think so).

There's a similar issue report here, at least it seems related, though I've been unable to resolve my issue as the suggested code is not a drop-in and I'm my JS skills are lacking at best ->
[Mouse position in SVG and RevealJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949001/mouse-position-in-svg-and-revealjs)

I was hoping someone could help me pinpoint a potential solution, maybe that of the other stack easily can be adapted (I do need the scaling function, I know I could initialize RevealJS with a percentage option, but that will effectively break scaling on any smaller devices).

This is the code part that seems related, in my case the second else `if( scale > 1 && features.zoom ) { ... }` is triggered and the scaling creates a bad offset depending on resolution.

```
var size = getComputedSlideSize();

        // Layout the contents of the slides
        layoutSlideContents( config.width, config.height );

        dom.slides.style.width = size.width + 'px';
        dom.slides.style.height = size.height + 'px';

        // Determine scale of content to fit within available space
        scale = Math.min( size.presentationWidth / size.width, size.presentationHeight / size.height );

        console.log("Size:"+size.presentationWidth);
        console.log("Size:"+size.width);


        console.log("1:"+scale);


        // Respect max/min scale settings
        scale = Math.max( scale, config.minScale );
        console.log("2:"+scale);
    scale = Math.min( scale, config.maxScale );
        console.log("3:"+scale);


        // Don't apply any scaling styles if scale is 1
        if( scale === 1 ) {
            dom.slides.style.zoom = '';
            dom.slides.style.left = '';
            dom.slides.style.top = '';
            dom.slides.style.bottom = '';
            dom.slides.style.right = '';
            transformSlides( { layout: '' } );
        }
        else {
            // Prefer zoom for scaling up so that content remains crisp.
            // Don't use zoom to scale down since that can lead to shifts
            // in text layout/line breaks.
            if( scale > 1 && features.zoom ) {
                dom.slides.style.zoom = scale;
                dom.slides.style.left = '';
                dom.slides.style.top = '';
                dom.slides.style.bottom = '';
                dom.slides.style.right = '';
                transformSlides( { layout: '' } );
            }
            // Apply scale transform as a fallback
            else {
                dom.slides.style.zoom = '';
                dom.slides.style.left = '50%';
                dom.slides.style.top = '50%';
                dom.slides.style.bottom = 'auto';
                dom.slides.style.right = 'auto';
                transformSlides( { layout: 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale('+ scale +')' } );
            }
        }
```

I've created a codepen to illustrate the issue, resize it from small to max size and check the mouse tooltip, there will be a small to massive offset between where the mouse is and what tooltip point shows except when the scale is 1:1.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVLazG

Any and all help would be welcome. If there's a way to process the graph in a way that would retain a better mouse position I'd be grateful both suggestions and code (banged my head for a couple of hours on different approaches without luck).

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by setting transform's `scale` on the wrapping div. You can read more about on Highcharts github [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2405).

There is a workaround for this which seems to work in your example:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, 'normalize', function (proceed, event, chartPosition) {
    var e = proceed.call(this, event, chartPosition);

    var element = this.chart.container;
    if (element && element.offsetWidth && element.offsetHeight) {

        var scaleX = element.getBoundingClientRect().width / element.offsetWidth;
        var scaleY = element.getBoundingClientRect().height / element.offsetHeight;
        if (scaleX !== 1) {
            e.chartX = parseInt(e.chartX / scaleX, 10);
        }
        if (scaleY !== 1) {
            e.chartY = parseInt(e.chartY / scaleY, 10);
        }

    }
    return e;
});
```

live example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxzPKq

Comment: This is potentially great news, I'll wrap this up in my local code and have a go to see if this indeed might resolve my issue (I'd be really happy).

Comment: Update: At least on Chrome the new live example seems to only work when making it smaller, but on a higher res screen when it get's bigger it seems to not work unless I'm missing something. Still trying to understand the code and reading up on the referenced github discussion.

Comment: @organizer, I see that you have a working solution here and I'm not sure why didn't you accept it. Your original code is working fine directly in the browser. Finally, let me tell you that this is quite different from that question because the issu there was with Firefox.