# Zoom at the position of the mouse pointer

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

I have an SVG that I would like to extend with the ability to zoom. This is currently done like this (.ts):

```
@HostListener('wheel', ['$event'])
  onMouseWheel(event: WheelEvent) {
    const svgpicture = document.getElementById('svg');
    const zoomfactore = Math.sign(event.deltaY);
    this.zoom -= (zoomfactore * 0.1);

    if (this.zoom <= 0.25) {
      this.zoom = 0.25;
    }
    if(zoomfactore>0){
      svgpicture.style.setProperty('transition','all 200ms ease-in')
    }
    if(zoomfactore<0){
    svgpicture.style.setProperty('transition','all 200ms ease-out')
    }

    const scale = 'scale('.concat(this.zoom.toString()).concat(')');
    svgpicture.style.setProperty('transform', scale)
```

My html file looks like this

```
<div id="container">
<svg id="svg"> .... </svg>
</div>
```

This also works as desired. Only the zoom is always in the middle of the SVG image. I would like to have this but at the position of the mouse pointer.

I have tried the following

```
    const positionx = event.pageX;
    const positiony = event.pageY;
    // const positionx = event.X;
    // const positiony = event.Y;
    // const positionx = event.clientX;
    // const positiony = event.clientY;
    const position = positionx.toString().concat(' ').concat(positiony.toString());
    svgpicture.style.setProperty('translate', position)
```

Unfortunately nothing worked. I guess I still have to relate or convert them. There is missing the idea at the moment.
Units of the returned values I have not found out yet.

Hopefully someone here has a good idea how I can solve the challenge.

Comment: `transform` style property can (and should) actually combine several transforms like `scale(1.1) translate(10px, -10px)`

Comment: But not so that I also zoom in at the point of my cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is combination of `transform-origin` attribute, `transform` style property and conversion of mouse coordinates to SVG space from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298658/mouse-position-inside-autoscaled-svg).

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('#svg');
const circle = document.querySelector('#circle');
const point = new DOMPoint();
let scaleFactor = 1.1;

function cursorPoint(event){
  point.x = event.clientX; point.y = event.clientY;
  point.z = 0; point.w = 0;
  return point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
function updateScale(value) {
  scaleFactor = Math.max(1.0, Math.min(value, 5));
  circle.style.setProperty('--scale-factor', scaleFactor);
}

circle.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  let svgCoords = cursorPoint(event);
  let bbox = event.target.getBBox();
  let offsetX = svgCoords.x - bbox.x;
  let offsetY = svgCoords.y - bbox.y;
  event.target.setAttribute('transform-origin', `${offsetX} ${offsetY}`);
});
circle.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
  updateScale(scaleFactor + event.wheelDelta * 0.005);
  event.preventDefault();
});
circle.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
  updateScale(1.1);
});
```

```css
#circle{
  --scale-factor: 1.1;
  transition-property: transform, transform-origin;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}
#circle:hover {
  transform: scale(var(--scale-factor));
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="200px" width="200px">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="checkers" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="1"/>
  <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="url(#checkers)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ethlice functions are obsolete (createSVGPoint, mousemove, event.target.getBBBox). To make the example compile, I had to make some changes. 
Unfortunately the zoom point jumps back and forth or to the edge of the image.

Comment: Only `SVGPoint` is deprecated, everything else is perfectly fine (might lack *typescript* support, however).