# How can I change the position of the element which is continuously rotating using CSS or JQuery (without position: absolute)?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

Here is my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L3jLna2L/1/).

**What is the problem?**

> I have two `<div>`s i.e with **red** and **blue** classes. **red** is
>   just to indicate original position of **blue** class. Rest everything, we are
>   only focusing on **blue**.
>
> Now, when I `hover` on **blue**, it starts rotating continuously till
>   infinity. And when it rotates more than **95deg** approximately, we
>   can see that some part of **blue** class gets out of the left of the body.
>   Similarly, when it reaches on the upper-half during rotation, it's some part
>   gets out on the upper side of the body.

**What I want:**

> I want is that when the **blue** starts hiding to the left, it should
>   be pushed from left so as to get shifted to the right and thus
>   avoiding from getting hidden. Similarly, it should be pushed from the
>   top gradually as it starts hiding on the upper side.
>
> You can apply `margin` or even `translate` for changing the position
>   of the **blue**. But, **position absolute is not allowed in this case.** So, I have to stick at that. Sorry about that.

I have got exhausted knowing what I have been doing wrong. It would be a great help if you help me find out. Thanks in advance.

[**Note**: *I can't change the origin of rotation. It has to be top-left of the body forcing **blue** from hiding.*]

```js
$(function(){ 
  var blueDivOffset = $(".blue").offset();
  var blueDivOffsetTop = blueDivOffset.top;     //20
  var blueDivOffsetLeft = blueDivOffset.left;   //28
  
  function rotate() {
    //console.log(blueDivOffsetTop); 
    //console.log(blueDivOffsetLeft);
    
    if( 0 < blueDivOffsetTop < 20 ) {
      var operation = 20 - blueDivOffsetTop;
      $(".blue").css({"margin-top": operation+"px"});
    } else if (blueDivOffsetTop < 0){
      var operation = 20 + (-1) * blueDivOffsetTop;
      $(".blue").css({"margin-top": operation+"px"});
    } else {
      $(".blue").css({"margin-top": 0});
    }
    
    if( 0 < blueDivOffsetLeft < 28 ) {
      var operation = 28 - blueDivOffsetLeft;
      $(".blue").css({"margin-left": operation+"px"});
      //console.log("hi");
    } else if (blueDivOffsetLeft < 0){
      var operation = 28 + (-1) * blueDivOffsetLeft;
      $(".blue").css({"margin-left": operation+"px"});
    } else {
      $(".blue").css({"margin-left": 0});
    }
    var margLeft = $(".blue").css("margin-left");
    console.log(margLeft);
  }
  
  $(".blue").hover(function(e){
    to = window.setInterval(rotate, 1);
  },function(e) {
    window.clearInterval(to);
  });
  //setInterval(rotate, 1);
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div > div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
}
.main {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.blueParent {
    
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0,0);
    transform-origin: 25px 25px; */ 
    background-color: blue;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0,-50px);
    transform-origin: 25px -25px;
    
}
.blue:hover {
    animation: rotate 5s linear infinite reverse;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0 { transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(0,-50px); }
  25% { transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(0,-50px); }
  50% { transform: rotate(-270deg) translate(0,-50px); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg) translate(0,-50px); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue" id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021522/move-and-limit-motion-of-a-div-inside-an-other-div or this https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/bouncing-a-ball-around-with-html5-and-javascript/

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept? ... or it simply didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic setup to do that. The main trick is to first rotate and then re-position.

Now you can elaborate with the amount of degree and x/y movement to get the exact rotation/position.

*I added more steps when I tested this and that will like will be needed to have it rotate smoother, and as well start the re-position earlier so it doesn't touch the edges, though those adjustments is somewhat time consuming so I leave them to you :)*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
.main {
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 0px 50px;
}
.main:hover .blue {
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite reverse;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg)
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(300px, 250px) rotate(-90deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(300px, -50px) rotate(-180deg)
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(0, -50px) rotate(-270deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue" id="blue"></div>
</div>
```