# Getting mouse position inside parent div with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery get mouse position within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)

I have a page and inside that page I have a div.
If the user clicks inside that div it'll store the X/Y co-ordinates of where they clicked inside that div.

E.g. if I clicked in the top left corner of the div (no matter where the div was placed on the page) it'd return approximately 0, 0.

Is this even possible? and if so, could you tell me how - or even point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like it's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `pageX` property of the event to get the x coordinate relative to the page and `pageY` to get the y coordinate, then substract the element's coordinates to get the position relative to the element.

```
$( '#target' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WhrFt/

Official tutorial on jquery.com: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: Thanks, a big help -- this is perfect!

Comment: this doesn't work if some descendant element uses relative or absolute positioning.