# Restrict a click to a specific shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have this image/polygon defined in css like this:

```
.post-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 420px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddc;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 50%, 50% 0, 0 50%);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

you can see the image:

[image: Maintain click event in CSS shape]

It defines a sort of rectangle, this is a clickable image that redirects to another page, and people are able to click in any part of the rectangle but I only want them to click on the polygon. Anyone knows how can I do this here in my code?

[**Fidde**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/T4BSg/2/)

Comment: why not just use an image map?

Comment: It would be great if you could make a fiddle. You can also check this answer witch is similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23188768/1811992

Comment: @web-tiki added the fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/T4BSg/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CSS solution**

You may maintain the boundaries of the diamond shape and make only the part with the image clickable by using css transform properties. The point is to use the [skew](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew) property so that the link actualy has a diamond shape and therefore isn't clickable outside this shape (see following demo and screenshot). Then, you need to "counter transform" the content so it isn't skewed.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yWzH5/)**

screenshot :

[image: diamond shape with proper boundaries]

*Relevant CSS :*

```
a{
    width: 216px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;

    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* to reduce pixelisation on borders in chrome */

    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;


    -webkit-transform: translate(55%,0) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(55%,0) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
    transform: translate(55%,0) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.post-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    height: 432px;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-h-c-250-432-8.jpg) center center;
    background-size: cover; 

    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;

    -webkit-transform:   skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translate(-50%,0);
    -ms-transform:   skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translate(-50%,0);
    transform:   skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Comment: This is a cool solution, sadly it's not too extendable to other shapes though.

Comment: It can be adapted to other shapes, all the ones you can create in CSS and has the advantage of not using any JS.

Comment: You see, i didnt accepted your answer as correct, but Its realy a good answer, Nit gave me more support so since his answer is correct and was first i accept it, but you're answer is quite amazing. Thanks for the reply and best wishes.

Comment: no worries @gn66 choise is yours to make. Happy to have helped :)

Comment: @NicolasBorda for triangles, you can use the technique described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work/24808936#24808936) and this demo: [triangle with hover effect](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/icClo)

Comment: @web-tiki thank you for that answer, I had come across that answer and you do a great job explaining everything. What I couldn't workout is how todo a an equilateral triangle, Could you please help with the values I need to alter to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

This can easily be achieved with SVG paths and Javascript. Sample implementation is as follows:
Create a transparent SVG shape that covers the area you want to make clickable. Then attach a click listener to the path with Javascript.

[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9BGUV/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="sample_image">
    <svg id="cover" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M 70,266 L 196,56 320,266 196,478 z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sample_image {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4zEw.png');
    width: 448px;
    height: 701px;
}

#cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#cover path {
    fill: transparent;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#cover path').on('click', function() {
    //Used only for sample output
    $('#status').append("<span>Click received.</span> ");
})
```

Comment: Can u explain your answer? Fiddle is realy not working so i'm not understanging what it does. How can I integrate the code u made, here: jsfiddle.net/T4BSg/2 ?

Comment: Updated fiddle so clicks are notified of visually.

Comment: You haven't included jQuery as I have in my Fiddle. You don't need it, I've simply used it for ease of selectors for the example. See http://jsfiddle.net/dMw23/

Answer (score 3):

For a pure HTML/CSS solution, you can add an empty href on top of the image, with a fixed height and width. Like:

```
.clickable-href{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:red; /* remove this to make the anchor transparent */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5K72/)

Or if it's an `img` tag, then add a `relative` parent and use `position:absolute` the the anchor:

```
.relative a{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red; /* remove this to make the anchor transparent */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5K72/3/)

Comment: @GaurangTandon use JavaScript as the last resort :)

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply! If I understood your answer you define a square to click. I want only to click inside the poligon/diamond in that specific shape.

Comment: @gn66 you can use two _inline_ elements, like `span` to create top and bottom triangle - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/S5K72/4/)

Comment: @Vucko Thanks again for the reply :) Perhaps I didnt explain me right, see this image taken from your fiddle: http://s7.postimg.org/ikwipqb8n/Prt_Scr_capture_6.jpg
I just dont want that people can click on the red area, in your example and in mine they can, but they shouldn't :/

Comment: @gn66 then make four small `spans` and position them `absolutly`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use JavaScript I suppose. Get the coordinates of the click. Match if they are in the allowed range. And if they are not, use `return false`.

Read: [Getting mouse position inside parent div with javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021751/getting-mouse-position-inside-parent-div-with-javascript-jquery)

**Pseudo-Code**:

```
element.onclick = function(){
    if(check range here){
        // user clicked in allowed range
    }else{
        // user did not click in allowed range
        return false; // stop event from working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution using the css3 transform property, leave you the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eiqqen/8U2K7/)
Only using html and css

Reorder the tags:

```
<div class="post-wrapper"><a href="#"></a></div>
```

And the css:

```
.post-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 420px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddc;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 50%, 50% 0, 0 50%);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.post-wrapper a{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    left: -30%;
    top: 2.3%;
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.6, .6) skew(10deg, 10deg) translate(0px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.6, .6) skew(10deg, 10deg) translate(0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.6, .6) skew(10deg, 10deg) translate(0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.6, .6) skew(10deg, 10deg) translate(0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.6, .6) skew(10deg, 10deg) translate(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this wasn't the case in 2014, but now browsers respect `clip-path` when establishing the clickable area for an element. Theoretically then, the example given (prefix notwithstanding) in the question should behave as was originally desired now.

Here is a codepen demonstrating this:

https://codepen.io/joshdavenport/pen/GRdPxyw

[image: Demonstration of clip-path affecting]