# How to get mousedown offset relative to an img target element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `mousedown` event handler on an `img` element:

```
$('#some_image').bind({
    mousedown: function(e) {
        var img = e.target;
        var relpos = ???;
    }
  })
```

How can I get the location of the `mousedown` *relative to* `img`?  Relative, that is, to any one of `img`'s corners, whichever is easiest.

FWIW, I'm using jQuery.

(Sorry for the dumb question.  I imagine the answer must be trivial, but I can't find it, and it's driving me insane...)

EDIT: OK, here's the answer:

```
$('#some_image').bind({
    mousedown: function(e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relpos = [e.pageX - offset.left, e.pageY - offset.top];
        // etc.
    }
  })
```

Actually, I found that for what I'm doing it's better to subtract `Math.round(offset.left)` and `Math.round(offset.top)` rather than the raw offsets, since the latter are not always integers (go figure).

BTW, at least according to Firebug, the event's `offsetX` and `offsetY` are undefined, and `layerX` and `layerY` are not even listed among its members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from this post  [jQuery get mouse position within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)

```
$("#something").click(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer was the closest one to what I finally settled on (see my EDIT to the original post).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use layerX and layerY.

```
$('#some_image').bind({
    mousedown: function(e) {
        var img = e.target;
        console.log(e.layerX+","+ e.layerY);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's event object has pageX and pageY properties which they returns the position of the mouse pointer, relative to the left edge of the document.

So, simply you need to get that positions on click event and compare with target element's position.

Official jQuery documentation have nice examples about [Mouse position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position) tracking.