# jQuery: click and get the width

Tags: jquery

If the user clicks somewhere in the bar, can the indicator get that width. (Similar to a progress bar in a video)

```
$(function(){        
  $("#play").click(function() {
    $("#indicador").animate({"width": "150px"}, 8400);
  });
});
```

Here to try and play:http://jsfiddle.net/SwkaR/7/

Comment: This other stack overflow question should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the coordinates where the user clicked from the [`Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object passed as first parameter to the `click` event handler. You simply have to subtract the element offset relative to the page from [`$.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the position relative to the element.

```
$("#bar").click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var relativeY = e.pageY - offset.top;
    // Do something with these
});
```

For example, here's a [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/SNzBZ/) which allows you to place the indicator by clicking anywhere in the bar.

Comment: I love this solution because it is so clean and clear and made with just a few lines of code. And the explanation helped a lot to understand. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I've gone for http://jsfiddle.net/SwkaR/13/ and http://jsfiddle.net/SwkaR/18/

```
$(function(){

  $("#play").click(function() {
    $("#indicator").animate({"width": "150px"}, 8400);
  });
    $('#bar').click(function(e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
         var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        $("#indicator").animate({"width": relX + "px"});
    });
    $('#indicator').click(function(e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
         var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        $("#indicator").animate({"width": relX + "px"});
    });        
});
```

Set Indicator width to the point where user clicked in the bar

Using [jQuery get mouse position within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element) as a reference to get the Mouse Click Position in the bar and set indicator to that

Comment: It works well but only to make the bar grow. It then it clicks to a smaller position doesn't get that. Anyway it is a first step!

Comment: My Indicator click detection might be borked when the bar is in the way.

Comment: So duplicate the $('#bar').click function for $('#indicator').click I've updated my solution to include #indicator click detect (Not tested)

Comment: Lovely glad to of been of help :-D

Answer (score 0):

To get the indicator width, use `$("#indicator").width()`

### JQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $("#play").click(function() {
    $("#indicator").animate({"width": "150px"}, 8400);
  });

    $("#indicator").click(function() {
        alert($(this).width());
    });

});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/SwkaR/14/)**