# How can I get left and top coordinates of KineticJS stage?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to get the co-ordinates of the mouse cursor and do operations when it leaves my KineticJS stage. But I need to get the co-ordinates of the mouse relative to the stage canvas. So when the mouse cursor leaves the stage from left edge, the coordinate should be 0, when it leaves from the top, y coordinate should be 0 regardless of where the stage is placed in the webpage. I wrote a function but I get NaN in the console.

container is the div inside which the stage is placed

```
function checkBounds(e) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("container");
    console.log(e.clientX - stage.getX() + "," + e.clientY - stage.getY());
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some jquery code that finds the container offsets on the webpage.

```
    var containerOffset=$("#container").offset();
    var offsetX=containerOffset.left;
    var offsetY=containerOffset.top;
```

And here's how you get the exact mouse position inside your event handler

```
    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here

    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using jQuery ? Especially the .offset() method ? EDIT: nm, answered my question. Used offsetLeft and offsetTop methods