# Canvas Kineticjs - position mouse is wrong

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have text line at first after that i have canvas
but position mouse on canvas it's wrong (zero of y position now = height of text line)

**http://jsfiddle.net/dSC26/**

```
<div id="output">output</div>
<div id="container"></div>

yoda.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $('#output').html('position mouse on canvas: '+'x: ' + e.clientX + ', y: ' + e.clientY); 
});
```

How can i fix that, thanks!.

Comment: Are you saying that the canvas should display x: 0 , y: 0  instead of 21?

Comment: yes, i want display 0,0. i don't want hardfix like (e.clientY-21), because i don't know exactly, it's 20 not 21

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element

Comment: @plalx i don't using jquery here. i using jquery for display message and it's not working for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `event.offsetX/Y` or `event.layerX/Y` properties.

Have a look here -> http://jsfiddle.net/dSC26/2/

```
yoda.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var offsetX = e.offsetX || e.layerX,
        offsetY = e.offsetY || e.layerY;

    $('#output').html('position mouse on canvas: '+'x: ' + offsetX + ', y: ' +  offsetY); 
});
```

Comment: Np ;) However, you should have a look at browser compatibility to make sure it's supported everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just use stage.getMousePosition().  Example here:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/

You can also sue stage.getTouchPosition() for touch events, or stage.getPointerPosition() for mouse or touch events