# Detect mouseover in 10px of div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have like a div like this:

------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------

It is possible with javascript or jquery and **without using any aditional tags** to detect when the user overs this area which is 10px

----------------**--**
----------------**--**
----------------**--**
----------------**--**

I know how to make it using aditional tags, but I would like to know if there is a better option, **using only javascript.**

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element

Answer (score 1):

You can attach event handler in JavaScript without any additional tags. For example if you have a DIV like this:

```
<div id="xdiv" style="width:100px; height:100px; border: solid 1px black" />
```

in pure JavaScript you can attach `onmousemove` like this:

```
document.getElementById("xdiv").onmousemove = function(e) {
    var evt = e || event;

    if (this.offsetWidth - evt.offsetX > 10) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "green"
    }
}
```

When you move the mouse over DIV it will become green if you move within 10px of the right side. Otherwise it will be red.

Live demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/25SXW/3/