# Getting the position of a mouse click inside the parent div javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a long rectangular div (parent) with several smaller div (child) inside it. I want to click anywhere on the long rectangular div (including the child divs) to show the offset from the left of the parent div.

Currently this javascript code only works when I click outside the small divs, as soon as I click inside the child div, it shows me the offset of the child div. I'm quite new to javascript and can't seem to find relevant answers to this.

I hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

```
window.onload = function(){
    parentDiv.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        alert(e.offsetX);
}, false);
```

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Post a demo here http://jsfiddle.net , Please

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get mouse position within an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)

Comment: Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/VGx2v/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `getClientRects` method with the `clientX` event value to get the net offset coordinate:

```
var offset = this.getClientRects()[0];
alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/VGx2v/3/)

Comment: I find it difficult to learn javascript such as seek functions like this, I have no other way of searching for possible ways of solving it apart from directly ask, do you have suggestions on good references that might be useful?

Comment: Thank you. Works great for calculating positions of elements that have transforms applied

Answer (score 4):

First, I recommend learning a bit about DOM event bubbling and capturing.  This is a DOM thing, not so much a Javascript thing, but essential to know.  Rather than repeat it here, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

So, when you click on the child `div`, the event is first presented to the element that fired the event, which is the child `div`.  It, however, does not have an event handler so the event bubbles up to the parent `div`.  It does have a handler, which is invoked with the event object passed as arg `e`.  Different browsers have different implementations of the event object.  Since you're using `offsetX` you're probably using IE (or Opera) and not Chrome, Safari, or Firefox. According to this [doc from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534305(v=vs.85).aspx), `offsetX()` "sets or retrieves the x-coordinate of a pointer's position **relative to the object firing the event**".  So, even though it's the parent `div`'s event handler running, you'll get the position relative to the child since it was the object firing the event.

Since you are new to JavaScript, I'll add this: due to the many incompatibilities between browsers, it is STRONGLY recommend that you use a JavaScript library that will handle these giving you a single normalized API. Your life will be easier, you'll be able to do much more, and your code will work on more than just IE. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a very popular one (and is in itself very beautiful). Read about jQuery's normalized [Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the problem was giving `z-index : -1` to child div.

```js
parentDiv = document.getElementByClassName("parentDiv");
window.onload = function(){
    parentDiv.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        alert(e.offsetX);
}, false);
```

and in HTML I had :

```html
<div classname = "parentDiv">
   <div classname = "childDiv"> I am child</div>
</div>
```

and in css :

```css
.childDiv{
   z-index : -1;
}
```