# Can you get ClientX && ClientY in reference to a selector instead of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i call a function, i get:  window.event.clientX and window.event.clientY from a global function, paste.

Im trying to paste at the coordinates, but they are off by some info i am working to resolve.

i was just going to take:

```
window_data:  {top,left}
```

and substract:

```
stage_div_offset:  {top,left}
```

to get the actual offset but that seems to also be off by a bit.  Around 40 pixels in both X and Y directions.   I assumed this is due to maybe margin or padding or something like that.

What i was really curious of is, Is there a way to get the `X` and `Y` of the mouse in reference to a div or other `htmlElement`?

I wasnt sure if there was a function which i could pass in a selector, or if using something like jquery, there would actually be a function or something for the selector called:  mouse.

I do feel this following Topic is relevant, though not sure if it makes mine a dup:
**[jQuery get mouse position within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)**

**Edit:**  Originally i was doing the following code:

```
var stage = $("#stage").offset(),
    results = { 
        left: window.event.clientX - stage.left, 
        top: window.event.clientY - stage.top 
    };
```

**Edit 2:** none of the current answers seem to be working, partially because my browser is not recognizing the mouseEvent, so it cant get the screens location.

I wrote the following to try to get the mouselocation

```
var MouseLocation = {};
MouseLocation.Left = 0;
MouseLocation.Top = 0;
MouseLocation._event;
MouseLocation.get_position = function () { return { left: MouseLocation.Left, top: MouseLocation.Top }; }
MouseLocation.attach = function () {
    MouseLocation._event = function (e) {
        var loc = { left: e.clientX, top: e.clientY }
        MouseLocation.Left = loc.left;
        MouseLocation.Top = loc.top;
    };
    $("#stage").on("mousemove", MouseLocation._event);
}
MouseLocation.detach = function () {
    $("#stage").off("mousemove", MouseLocation._event);
}
MouseLocation.ping = function () {
    MouseLocation.attach();
    $("#stage").mousemove();
    MouseLocation.detach();
}
```

so that way, inside of my event, i can just say:

MouseLocation.ping();
MouseLocation.get_position();

but it doesnt seem to like:   $("#stage").on("mousemove")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [postion()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) to:

Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

Comment: I added some code.  Right now, i was just subracting the of stage.offset() from event.client*.  Are you saying that instead i should do event.client* - {stage.parent().offset() + stage.position()}

Comment: It seems that one of the issues im having at the moment is that when i paste, it doesnt recognize what:  window.event.clientX etc is.   Am i missing something?    Right now, I click and copy, but im just trying to get the coords of whereever the position of the mouse is.  It seems like when i do paste, it cant find my mouse or something.  I think it is because event is being used for click stuff, so a lot of the things related to the mouse is 0 or undefined.

Comment: @RodringoDela above was making not that offset accounts for padding, margin, borders, etc. Im thinking the deviation might be related to that, but i cant find much more

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the document coordinates of the mouse and substract the coordinates of the element:

```
relX = e.clientX-element.offset().left;
relY = e.clientY-element.offset().top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4scbu/1/

The advantage to offset() is that margin and paddings are included into the calculations.

Comment: since i have margin and paddings etc, would it not make more sense to use position then?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I was mistaken, it's the advantage of offset().