# jquery each index only working for first item

Tags: jquery, each, background-color

I cant get this to work for all items. This code only works for the first li item. I believe the error is still in the basic jquery. Colorthief is a plugin that grabs the rgb value from image which im trying to apply to each hover.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".popup-gallery li").each(function (index) {
        var $myImage = $(this).find('img');
        var colorThief = new ColorThief();

        //Grabs 8 swatch color palette from image and sets quality to 5 (0 =slow, 10=default/fast)
        var cp = colorThief.getPalette($myImage[0], 8, 5);

        //Sets background to 3rd color in the palette.
        $(this).find('.hover').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + cp[2][0] + ',' + cp[2][1] + ',' + cp[2][2] + ')');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post the HTML also for this?

Comment: @A.Wolff I disagree - the `img` is within the `li`. So it would be the first `img` inside each `li`.

Comment: Please leave a comment after editing so I get informed about the update.

Comment: I'm trying to do a fiddle but i cant get it to work at all... https://jsfiddle.net/q2eL8u4t/1/ maybe I just don't know how to use it properly

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery click on border of a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217266/jquery-click-on-border-of-a-div)

Comment: Does that link relate here @RinoRaj. I found you answering in other link.. ;)

Comment: @niksos.. Check for console error?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this suggestion as a comment but I dont have the needed privilege. Anyways from what I get from you jQuery .pop-gallery is the classname for the ul element. Since your HTML is not here, if thats the case please try something like

```
    $(".pop-gallery").children("li").each(function(){
```

}

Comment: Results are still the same :( only working for first item. No difference with $myImage[index]

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as well?

Comment: Please check one more thing.In the code above you have used $myImage[0] when it should be $myImage[index]

Comment: Yep I tried that. The error comes from that line you're correct var cp = colorThief.getPalette($myImage[index], 8, 5); 

and console is pointing to the colorthief plugin as well TypeError: a is undefined so i believe this might be a lost cause.